# floated elements are overflowing out of the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a fluid layout. I gave width  values of the divs in percentage. But specified height in px. So when I fold my browser the contents are folding but the floated divs are overflowing out of the container. So I tried to change all the divs height in % but its not working. Please suggest me how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Please add your markup with styles to the question.

Comment: please add your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ then it will easy to debug it

Comment: I guess he wants the clearfix http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: please post your complete code here

Comment: for last 10 min i was trying to post the code but not able to..:(

Comment: Have you tried overflow:auto.. with fixed height... or provide some code here...

Comment: ya i tried overflow: auto..it gives me a scrolling...but not tried with height in px..height is in %...

Comment: body
{
 height: 700px;
}
.container-fluid
{
 border: 1px solid #000;
 height: 100%;
}
.row-fluid
{
 border: 1px solid  #C00;
 height: 100%;
}
.out
{
 position: relative;
 left: 3.5%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 height: 100% !important;
 border-top: 5px solid #000;
}
.in
{
 position: relative;
 right: 3.5%;
 top: 7%;
 border: 1px solid  #C93;
 height: 85% !important;
 width: 90% !important;
 overflow: auto;
}
.header
{
 width: 100% !important;
 height: 25.5%;
 border: 1px solid  #C93;
}

Comment: .footer
{
 height: 0%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: 0 !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 position: relative;
 top: 10.7%;
}
.box1
{
 border: 1px solid #F6C;
 margin: 0px !important;
 position: relative;
 top: 14.5%;
 height: 60%;
}
.box2
{
 border: 1px solid #F6C;
 position: relative;
 top: 14.5%;
 height: 60%;
}
.box3
{
 border: 1px solid #F6C;
 position: relative;
 top: 14.5%;
 height: 60%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Height with percent only works when the parent has a fixed height. See this : [CSS – why doesn’t percentage height work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-percentage-height)