# How can you use percentage heights in css when the parent's height is set to auto?

Tags: html, css, layout

At the moment I have a large `<div>` that I'd like to add a bottom margin to, to push it up from the bottom of the page. However this currently has no effect because its parent, the `<body>` tag, is smaller than it, as you can see here:

The body tag is highlighted in blue and brown, but you can see my div (the white border) extending below it.
[image: Example]

However if I apply the trick of setting the `<body>` and `<html>` tags to `height: auto` and `min-height:100%` to make sure they fill the entire page, all of my inner content loses its size, because they all use percentage heights and no longer have a parent with a fixed height.

How can you use percentage heights if the parent tag has a height of `auto`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do this. A percentage height on an element only works if the parent element has a specific height. See also: [CSS – why doesn’t percentage height work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesnt-percentage-height-work)