# CSS Fluid Image issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, fluid-images

My background of my site is responsive and works great.But I'm having issues with the images. I want them to look "fixed" as in the same position with the background no matter the resolution,. Example re-sizing the browser from 990px by 537px to 990px by 270px the image will look like it never moved because the width/height will expand or contract depending on the resolution of the browser.

Good news I figured the CSS to make the WIDTH of the image fluid with the background! Bad news is if I make height 100% or 14%, the height looks the same. Is it true that I need to specificity my height? Why not width? How?

```
#block-imageblock-4{
    width:26%;
    height:14%;
     margin-top:7%;
     margin-bottom:1%;
    margin-left:37%;
    margin-right:36.5%;
        max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;


}
```

SO my question is how would I show my image to look like its in the SAME position on the screen if my resolution is very large or very small? Please provide a example and not just a link. Like I said I figured out to make the width of the image fluid, just not the height but if you have a better way please share.

I'm using Drupal to build my site FYI.

<---------------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------->

Here are two example of what I am talking about. **Please ignore all images BUT the image labeled IMAGE1.**

CSS for Image1:

```
 #block-imageblock-4{
        width:26%;
        height:14%;
         margin-top:7%;
         margin-bottom:1%;
        margin-left:37%;
        margin-right:36.5%;
            max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;


    }
```

First Image- Browser Resolution: 480px by 356px

[image]

Second Image- Browser Resolution: 520px by 630px
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding in some javascript to reposition the images on window resize? Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm using CMS (Drupal) with a module that loads a image as a block. I'm trying to make the IMAGE on top of the background  fluid, not the background.

Comment: No but why would this matter? My width of my image is fluid just not my height.

Comment: this may help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesnt-percentage-height-work/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesnt-percentage-height-work/)

Comment: An illustration of what is wrong and what you want would be great.

Comment: I will attach one in a moment

Comment: illustration attached.

Comment: As you can see the background is fluid, the width of image is fluid, but not the image height.

Comment: did you read that other stackoverflow answer? You cannot have fluid height with pure css

Comment: Yes but I don't understand where the parent height should go? So it should be width:26%;, height:300px; max-width;100%, max-height:100%; ?

Comment: I'm a visual learning. An example would be great.

Comment: I understand that the example below will show the image at a height of 140px, but will how would I set the percentage of the height to match the browser reolution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesnt-percentage-height-work/  #working{
    width:80%;
    height:140px;
    background:orange;
}

Comment: you could use javascript to determine the window height and then change the image height accordingly

Comment: Any example's Chris M? My solution ended up no working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code in js fiddle:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobi22/E7Rfa/5/)

Here is how I did it with CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: black;
}

#master {
    position: relative;
}

#img {
    width: 23%;
    max-width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80%;
    height: 10%;
    max-height: 40px;
    margin-top: -80px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="master"> </div>
<div id="img"> </div>
```

You make an outer div ie master set it to relative position
the image itself you give the properties i mentioned edit the width and height according to the image size you have, and edit margin-top and margin-left to offset it to fit it exactly to the position you wish, and it will all work fluidly, hope that helps.

as well as editing the bottom:X%; (percentage number in the X)  to edit the position in the y-axis.

Comment: he wants the image size to be fluid as well as its position

Comment: hmm okay i changed the fiddle abit, is this what you meant? :  http://jsfiddle.net/bobi22/E7Rfa/4/

Comment: Michaelm. You just replicated my problem. The width is fluid but not the height.

Comment: okay, how about now?  http://jsfiddle.net/bobi22/E7Rfa/5/    play with  it's window to check the height and width fluidness  notice i did make the height fluid yet maxed it up to certain amout of pixels so the image won't distort (even tho it's just a square block)

Comment: happy to help, let me know if you need some help on tweaking it for your image.