# Set height of div to percentage of its container

Tags: html, css

I have a `.container` div that is `600px` max in width or else `100%`.

Inside this div is a `.content` div that I want to be 60% of the 100% of the container's width.

More generally I'm trying to make a responsive **rectangle** div instead of a **square**.

http://jsfiddle.net/7zE9x/ (The image inside the content *should* be overflown, and have a y-scroll bar)

That is

My HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Where my css looks like:

```
.container {
    background: black;
    padding: 3%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 60%; /* Set this to 400px, meaning that it won't be responsive */
}

.content img {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

if I set the height of the `.content` div to `400px` it does what I want but it is not a percentage (so on resize it doesn't change - i.e. when the width of the container is `200px` the content div's height should be `120px`).

Comment: If you set a percentage it will take the height / width from its parent. So somewhere you need to define a height / width. Maybe on your `.container` or even on the `body`.?

Comment: You seem to be [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesn-t-percentage-height-work), but do I have to specifically do it by setting a `px` constraint? or can I use a percentages throughout?

Comment: You could set the body to `100%`. But to set `.content` to `60%` every parent needs to have a `height` defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **height** for `.container` too.

If the child does not know height of parent how will it adjust it self based on percentage???

Take a look at **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zE9x/4/)**

```
body {
    padding: 80px;
}

.container {
    background: black;
    padding: 3%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height:500px;/* Set height as per your wish. */
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
    height:50%; /* Adjust height accordingly. */
}

.content img {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
```