# How to fix <div> height

Tags: html, css

My have a problem to make DIVs having fixed height. The following is the code.
All  contains some other elements except the `#gridDiv`. gridDiv will be attached a grid at run time. and I want the gridDiv occupy 60% of the screen no matter it has grid inside or not. And if the grid is too long to fit in the gridDiv DIV, I wish the gridDiv have a scroll bar.

Currently the gridDiv only has inline height. How can I achieve what I want? Thank you.

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="display: block">

    <div id="topDiv" style="display: block; height:20%; text-align:center"></div>

    <div id="bottomDiv" style="display: block; height:80%">
        <div id="gridDiv" style="display: block; height:80%"></div>
        <div id="buttonDiv" style="display: block; width:100%; height:20%; text-align:center"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You [can't give height as a percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesn-t-percentage-height-work) in CSS

Comment: @brandaemon yes you can, after you have set height to html and body elements. `html, body {height: 100%}`

Comment: @Leo Care to demonstrate with this [JSFiddle?](https://jsfiddle.net/oxoe017s/)

Comment: @brandaemon c'mon https://jsfiddle.net/oxoe017s/1/

Comment: Ah that `html` identifier is important

Comment: @brandaemon yes, since is parent to the `body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with your requirements and example code:

> `gridDiv` container must always take up 60% of the screen

Assuming your `div` looks like this: `<div class="gridDiv">` you can use the following code:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.gridDiv{
    height: 60%;
}
```

> `gridDiv` has a scroll bar if the content inside overflows

```
.gridDiv{
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

See the entire `div` with overflowing filler text on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxoe017s/2/).

Answer (score 4):

You can always use **CSS3's `vh`** (Viewport Height) unit: `#gridDiv{ height:60vh; }`. It'll make `gridDiv` 60% the viewport - no matter what (actually browser matters :) ).

- First of all, don't use inline CSS cause it's hard to work with and debug. **If it's for illustrative purpose - I'll use inline CSS too.**
- Your `#mainDiv` is missing `height`. Height relates on parent element height.
- You're probably missing to define height for your document
- Unless you have globally overwritten the DIV's `display` state, DIV is `block`-level element by default, so `display:block;` is redundant.
- DIV width full width by default (`auto`),

```
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}
```

To illustrate:

```css
html,
body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

div{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv" style="height:100%;">

  <div id="topDiv" style="height:20%;">20</div>

  <div id="bottomDiv" style="height:80%">
    <div id="gridDiv" style="height:80%">inner 80</div>
    <div id="buttonDiv" style="height:20%;">inner 20</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now back to your `#gridDiv` - you want it 60% the **viewport height** - so use `60vh` height - and add `overflow-y` (set to `scroll` or `auto`) to add a scrollbar (for if it's content exceeds that height):

```css
html,
body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

div{
  background: #ddd;
}

#mainDiv    {height:100%;} /* go to html, body height */
#topDiv     {height:20%}   /* 20% of #mainDiv */
#bottomDiv  {height:80%;}  /* 80% of #mainDiv */
  #gridDiv  {height:60vh; overflow-y:scroll;} /* 60% the viewport height */
  #buttonDiv{height:20%;}  /* 20% */

/*just to simulate long content*/ p{height:2000px;}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">

  <div id="topDiv">20%</div>

  <div id="bottomDiv">
    <div id="gridDiv"><p>longContent</p></div>
    <div id="buttonDiv">inner 20</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank all of you. These answers solve my problem. I was switch to another project, so I didn't reply you promptly. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

the parent of the div must have an explicit height property. Otherwise the parent div height is the length of its content. Simple solution sit to set`<body>` element `height property`.

```
<body style="height:500px">
```

Then you percentages for the inline elements will work. Alternatively you can capture the browser height during run time and set to the main body element.

If you want your div scrollable then you need to add `overflow:scroll` property.

```
<div id="gridDiv" style="display: block; height:80%; overflow:scroll;">
```

This code works with IE11, not sure other browsers.