# CSS - why I can't apply % on my height?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to apply % on my height, but I could not. Instead the div just accept px, someone know what I am doing wrong?

```
.left-bar{
        height:200px;
```

**// if I use px works ok but if I use % does not work**

css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border:1px dashed gray;
}

.left-bar{
    height:200px; // why I cannot use % for my height?
    width:30%;
    border:1px solid green;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="md-col-12">
        header
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="left-bar">
   <p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p><p>alfkj aslkdjf slkdjf lksajf lkasjd flkajsd flkja sdlfkj asldkfj laskdj flkasjdf </p>

    </div>

    </div>



    <div class="col-md-12">
    footer
    </div>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q7kjm9pn/1/

I tried do this:
[Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

is not duplicated
is not duplicated see:
edit: https://jsfiddle.net/q7kjm9pn/5/

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesn-t-percentage-height-work) why it doesn't work like you want it.

Comment: need to add heights to it's parents respectively : `.container-fluid` and `.col-md-12`. see here https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/20cj5yh4/

Comment: Here is the working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/rd4zvuur/1/

Comment: @MihaiT thanks, its almost what I whant, but look I defined the class left-bar for 100% and now that div is bigger than others one? how is possible because this div is should be 100% from the other. https://jsfiddle.net/20cj5yh4/2/

Comment: because you have border of 1px ( so 2 px in total ) . just add `box-sizing:border-box` on `.left-bar`