# how to increase <p:panel> border height (not width)

Tags: css, primefaces

I want to increase size of the `<p:panel>` height but not width. below code increases both height and width.

> `<p:panel id="pnlPrev" style="width: 85%; border:1;">`

I tried with the below code but its doesnt working

```
> <p:panel id="pnlPrev" style="height: 85%; border:1;">    
> <p:panel id="pnlPrev" style="height: 85%; width: 85%; border:1;">
```

both are not working.Please Anyone help me to increase size of panel height

Comment: [This may be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5658062/7053420)

Comment: Thanks :) its some how works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a somewhat related post here: [p:panel how to change border properties](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16293). I can't render the php code so I have made an html example with css. Make sure to add classes and then you have full control of the appearance of the p:panel. Set a width, then set a height that's not based on the width like the min-height I've chosen.

Your grid system will control how wide the box is to make it responsive, so take out my 50% wide declaration when you put your component within that grid system.

```css
.myPanelContent.ui-panel
{
   
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p class="myPanelContent ui-panel">THING</p>
```

Comment: this will work as external css but due to some restrictions i dont want to use external css. i need to put properties in inline only.

Comment: That's fine, then just inline all the styles on the element: style" border: 1px solid red; padding: 2em; width: 50%; min-height: 200px;"

Comment: Thanks Flick.finally its working by using padding: 2em; . before i tried with padding: 2px. i dont knw the difference between em and px. however its working now. :)

Comment: Hi Teja great news! Pixels are absolute units and 1em is one unit of your page's base font size. More here: https://www.sitepoint.com/power-em-units-css/

Answer (score 0):

Change it to an `inline-block` to define the height yourself

```
<p:panel id="pnlPrev" style="height: 85%; border:1; display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: <p:panel id="pnlPrev" style="width: 80%; height: 85%; border:1; display:inline-block;"> 
This one is also not working :(

Comment: Even when defining a px value for height?

Comment: if i gave px value, then entire border conflicted. i mean if i change height attribute with any number with px ,it doesn't change

Comment: finally its working by using padding: 2em;(above comment Nathaniel Flick solution ). before i tried with padding: 2px. i dont know the difference between em and px. however its working now. thanks