# How to change viewport settings for children components (make container to be 100vw/100vh for children)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, viewport-units

In my project I have react-static repository linked (with yarn link) with react repo.

```
"react": "^16.13.1"
"react-static": "^6.0.18"
```

From react-static repository I am importing multiple components which are used in react repo. I want to be able to use vw/vh units in react-static, so that they will display in react project in the way I described below.

The problem is how to make the div to be 100% width and 100% height of viewport for the children. I need to make things work this way:

```
<div className="wrapper">
<div className="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The inner div (imported from react-static) needs to have `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`. For example - if I set the wrapper size (react container) for `width: 400px; height: 200px;` (with window size 1920x1080) I want the inner container's viewport to change the way it will match wrapper size - so it will have `width: 400px; height: 400px;` but will behave like the wrapper is the whole window for it.

The only solution I found so far is to calculate size for the elements in the inner container.
Any suggestions?

Comment: so you want to get the max value?

Comment: If there are other children inside the wrapper, try arranging them with flex. There are a lot of tutorials for flexbox. Otherwise, if you just want the child to take partial space of the parent, you can play around with margins with percentage values.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the child to a percent height and it will give you a percentage of its parent div. There are some weird things about height as a percentage - for instance the parent div needs to have explicitly declared height (a percentage of height:auto will always be 0). Read the second answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-why-doesn-t-percentage-height-work), it will explain it better than I can.