# Responsive image in flexbox - with flex-direction:column not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some content that I want displayed in the viewport without scrolling. It contains a header, an image and some copy. The copy can be of variable length and must take priority over the image. Flexbox works as intended when `flex-direction:row` but when I use `flex-direction:column` the image does not respond in the same way - the image and copy bursts out of the container. As the height is changed, I want the image to shrink, with it's container:

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62fzS.jpg)

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/jeremygillies/pen/NWpxmpN?editors=1100)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
       Spanish Omelette
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <!-- <img src="https://runnerbeantours.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/how-to-cook-spanish-omelette.jpg">-->
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="copy">
        In order to make a perfect spanish omelette, the potatoes needs to be cut into small slices 2 milimeters thick, then clean the potatoes. You will need a lot of practice!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
body {
  background:grey;
  padding:15px;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.card {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:625px;
  background:white;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:10px;
  height:calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.card-header {
  background:orange;
  flex:0 1 auto;
}
.card-content {
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background:yellow;
  .copy {
      background:yellow;
   }
}
.image {
  flex:0 2 auto;
  background:green;
  padding:10px;
  img {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using `vw` on the parent's div. Smaller screens will look totally different than bigger ones. Also when you set the parent's height to a certain amount, you'll need to specify the inside elements heights as well. This will prevent overflowing. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658062/2855957).

Flex can take care of that.

The only thing you need to do here is telling the image to not overflow.

```
body {
  background:grey;
  padding:15px;
}
.container {
}
.card {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin: auto;
  width:625px;
  background:white;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:10px;
  height:calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.card-header {
  flex: 0 1 1;
  background:orange;

}
.card-content {
  background:yellow;
  flex: 0 1 1;
  .copy {
      background:yellow;
   }
}
.image {
  overflow: hidden;
  background:green;
  padding:10px;
  flex: 0 1 1;
  img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thibaut. That's really helpful. I'm not entirely sure why `overflow:hidden` should set the image correctly. Either way, it works :) - good point on vh too, I'll look for an alternative