# Why is the "width" property in CSS not working?

Tags: html, css

So when I change the width on my website it doesn't work I've tried changing position but it just will not work

HTML and CSS:

```css
.wrapper-main{
  display: block;
  height: 54%; !important
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-main">
        <section class="section-default">
            <h1 class="header">Signup</h1>
            <form action="includes/sign-up.inc.php" method="post">
             <label for="username" id="label">Username</label><br>
                <input  type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username goes here.">
                <br><br>
                <label for="e-mail" id="label">E-mail</label><br>
                <input  type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="E-mail goes here.">
                <br><br>
                <label for="pwd" id="label">Password</label><br>
                <input  type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password goes here.">
                <br><br>
                <label for="password" id="label">Password</label><br>
                <input  type="text" id="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Password goes here.">
                <br><br>
                <button type="Submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: the code is not enough to debug and understand your problem.

Comment: yeah, because here you set your ```width:0px;```

Comment: @KunalTanwar I debugged the code just fine. Take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @Nishant That is not the problem. No matter what you set `width` to, it won't change the result.

Comment: can you share screenshot of the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `width` value and `!important` value is, in this case, is invalid.

[image]

As you can see in the picture the property is invalid. Try to give width to a text form rather than a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you miss ; after your !important;

```
  height: 54% !important;
  width: 100px;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The browser marks the `!imortant;` as invalid. You did fix the width property though.

Comment: you need to check this out once  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658062/16639239