# Page doesn't display anything when I include the DOCTYPE... my 100th question?

Tags: html, css, doctype

### UPDATE

I started going line by line and this was the first CSS style that let the browser show things. In particular, the absolute positioning seems to be screwing things up... I don't know why. If I remove it, or change it to relative, then things show up, but obviously not in the right place.

```
#foo {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -500px;
    padding-top: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

As requested, [you can view the HTML markup here](http://hristo.oskov.com/new.txt). Note, however, that there is a lot of dynamic HTML being generated during page load that is not in the HTML markup linked here.

---

I'm not quite sure why, but when I include the HTML 5 doctype `<!doctype html>` at the top of my `.html` file, nothing displays. However, inspecting the source using Chrome's Developer Tools shows that everything is in the DOM and all the CSS properties are applied.

Huh!? Weird.

I started investigating and found that when I remove my stylesheet, i.e. when I remove this line...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/new.css" />
```

... things show up on the page, but obviously the styling is not applied. The full css file [can be found here](http://hristo.oskov.com/new.css).

Any ideas as to why this is happening; suggestions on fixes? I'm pretty sure my CSS is all valid but from what I've heard, the W3C CSS Validator doesn't validate CSS3 very well

Comment: Have you tried hard resetting your spacings at the top of your stylesheet (ie. html, body, div, span, p, img... etc) instead of using an asterisk? Not sure if that's the problem, but then again I'm not well versed yet in html5 quirks.

Comment: no... I removed the universal selector and it didn't help. I also tried using Eric Meyer's CSS reset. didn't help

Comment: While you're at it, change `@CHARSET` to `@charset`.

Comment: that didn't help either. ugh. thanks for your suggestions. I'm going to try going 1 by 1

Comment: Any chance we could get a look at your html head markup?

Comment: yeah... check out the update in a sec.

Comment: BTW, you have two html open tags in `new.txt` that you linked to.

Comment: 2 open html tags? I don't think so... the first line is the doctype declaration.

Comment: That's right, sorry. I eye-balled it too quickly; been at work for too long today.

Comment: get out of work :D its about that time isn't it? anyway, check out Chris Lively's answer below. He identified the issue. Check out the comments to see the solution and make a comment, please :)

Comment: Yeah, I just read it. Good call @Chris Lively - I didn't spot the hidden overflow until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using a very limited css file. Meaning a blank one.

Then start adding the selectors back in until it breaks.  Once that happens you should be able to find the problem.

**UPDATE:**
foo is overflowing wrapper.  Because of this it is completely hidden.

If you add "`border: solid 1px blue;`" to the #wrapper tag you'll see what I mean.

For more information see: [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Basically, the min-height setting on the #wrapper tag isn't doing anything because it's parent (#everything) doesn't have a height set.  The only way % heights work is if the parent elements define an actual height.

In this case you'd have to add the following:

```
html { height: 100%;}
body { height: 100%;}
#everything { height: 100%; ... }
```

Then your wrapper will start wrapping and you can go back to the way you had it.

---

Which leads us to the original question: Why does this work when the doctype is yanked out?

The answer is that the browser was falling back into quirks mode which took care of expanding those divs for you.

Comment: @Chris... you're right. I changed the positioning of `#foo` to `fixed` and it seems to achieve the same effect, but when I resize the window, the `min-width` property doesn't apply. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Chris... actually, just changing `#wrapper` to have visible overflow fixed the problem, but do you think that is a good solution?

Comment: @Hristo: That's a whole different problem.  min-width appears to be working in the short sample I put together that only has the #everything, #wrapper, and #foo tags.

Comment: @Hristo: I think you might want to figure out why #wrapper isn't doing what you want by wrapping the whole thing.

Comment: Without fixed dimensions, hiding your overflow will always truncate and produce this result.

Comment: @Chris... yeah I'll try to figure it out. I feel like this layout is a huge huge hack for what I'm trying to do.

@65Fbef05... aren't my dimensions fixed, 1000px?

Comment: Not for your `#wrapper` element - you have that set to a variable `100%`.

Comment: @Hristo: the missing link was the #everything declaration.  When it has a min-height set then it'll work.

Comment: @Chris... giving `#everything` a `min-height:100%` doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: @Chris... got it! not `min-height`, but `height: 100%` haha. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `<!DOCTYPE html>` rather than `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Then, without seeing the HTML page, I'd assume it was this: `#symbols-block [class *="-symbols"] {
 display: none;
}` If it's not that, then I'd follow Chris Lively's suggestion, but I'd probably start by just removing the CSS that sets `display: none;`