# 100% min-height for multiple divs?

Tags: css

If I have the following structure, for example, in a single page layout:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to set the minimum height of divs 1-4 to 100%, and position each div one under the other, using CSS alone? Ive created a page where the each div is 100% in height but problems begin to arise when the content of the divs are longer than the browser window.  There seem to be a lot of min-height 100% related articles but I haven't found one yet where there is more than one div involved.

Comment: Are you trying to show only one div at a time? What are you aiming for?

Comment: Hi, I am aiming to show each div, one under the other, all at the same time. I think I have it sorted now.

Comment: How did you do it? 
Was it the Min-Height Fast Hack?
{min-height:100%;

  height:auto !important;

  height:100%;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `height` or `min-height` to work correctly on a element, the parent of a element needs to have a explicit `height` declared. This goes all the way up in your DOM tree.

There shouldn't be a difference for rendering one or multiple div elements with min-height as far as I know, so yes it is possible to do the positioning with CSS alone.

See [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1622027/859762) for more details

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I should be able to do it now. Thanks for the info :)