# Jquery Selector to modify height of a div having some title

Tags: jquery

I want to modify the height of a div whose title contains (0%)

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div>

<div class='chartsbar' style="height: 0%; background-color: rgb(7, 134, 205); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 0.9730252100840335%; text-align: left;" title="11-09-2012 - 0 (0%)"></div>

<div class='chartsbar' style="height: 0%; background-color: rgb(7, 134, 205); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 0.9730252100840335%; text-align: left;" title="12-09-2012 - 0 (18%)"></div>


<div class='chartsbar' style="height: 0%; background-color: rgb(7, 134, 205); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 0.9730252100840335%; text-align: left;" title="13-09-2012 - 0 (10%)"></div>

</div>
```

I've tried like

```
$('div.chartsbar[title*="(0%)"]').height('1%');
```

but no luck

Comment: I don't think `title` is a valid div attribute. Maybe try using the new `data-` attributes in HTML: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml

Comment: Your JS code is correct. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RJP8/), but problem is in css. For instance, I've added height to wrapper div to make it work. Not sure how percentage height works, so I do not post this as an answer.

Comment: Check out this jsFiddle I've just created may help get you where you need ot be http://jsfiddle.net/w8adp/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.chartsbar[title="0%"]').css('height','1%');
```

Comment: @AmolJoshi wants it to _contain_ `(0%)`.

Comment: @JoeFletch need to find a div with class = 'chartsbar' and whose title contains 0% and need to modify the height of a such a div to 1%

Comment: @chokrijobs i tried ur code as well as  $('.chartsbar[title="0%"]').css('height','10px'); but no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.chartsbar[title*='(0%)']").css('height','100px');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/wmdZm/9/)​

Answer (score 0):

JS code is correct, but you must set some explicit height on your wrapper div. Right now height of wrapper div is 0 and 1% of 0 is still 0. For more extended explanation take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/1558311)

Comment: Even if i set it in pixel as  $('.chartsbar[title="0%"]').css('height','10px'); it is not working

Comment: Use your own code, not one provided by chokrijobs. Should be $('.chartsbar[title*="(0%)"]').height('10px');