# Div Height in Percentage

Tags: css, html, percentage, jsfiddle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

This needs to be a simple one but I why the height specified in percentage for a div is not apply to it.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  adsf
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
  width:80%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:#eee;
}
```

When I change height from % to px it works perfectly. % is as valid as px but why only px works and % not. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZedBee/j8bsS/2/) is the jsfiddle

**Edit** 
Though I missed the semicolon after 50% in original question which totally spoiled it. In fact what I intended to ask was why does the 50% does not make it consume the 50% of its container. It only takes its height from its content rather than 50% of its container.

Comment: Is this with quirks mode or standards mode? Heights work differently between modes.

Comment: @AliBassam I presume that is not the problem, since the OP says it works fine with px.

Comment: I know I missed the semicolon while changing the code but the question in fact was why does the 50% does not make it consume the 50% of its container. It only takes its height from its content rather than 50% of its container.

Comment: 1. missing `;` after 50% 2. if you want to use percentage height you need to specify height of all parent block elements of div http://jsfiddle.net/j8bsS/8/ 3. this question is asked few times every month, voting for close

Comment: Better explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It doesn't take the 50% of the whole page is because the "whole page" is only how tall your contents are. Change the enclosing `html` and `body` to `100%` height and it will work.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
div{
    height: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5YukJ/1/

[image]

^ Your document is only 20px high. 50% of 20px is 10px, and it is not what you expected.

[image]

^ Now if you change the height of the document to the height of the whole page (150px), 50% of 150px is 75px, then it will work.

Comment: tnx @derek so we when specifying height for a div in %age we need to set its parent container's height set

Comment: @ZedBee - If you don't specify the height, then it will just take the height of the container's content. So yes you will have to specify the height.

Comment: tnx. That really made things clear

Comment: Downvote probably because this is not a correct answer. This is only accurate if the div element is a child of the body element. See duplicate question.

Comment: @JonasÄppelgran - Disagree because `div` should be always in `body` according to the standards.

Comment: I mean this is only accurate if the div element is a DIRECT child of the body element.

Comment: Yes it is because this is the answer to his specific jsfiddle, not a general answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the `body` and the `html` a height too. Otherwise, the body will only be as high as its contents (the single div), and 50% of that will be half the height of this div.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8bsS/5/

Answer (score 1):

There is the semicolon missing (;) after the "50%"

but you should also notice that the percentage of your div is connected to the div that contains it.

for instance:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   adsf
  </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
  height:100px;
}
.container
{
  width:80%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:#eee;
}
```

here the height of your .container will be 50px. it will be 50% of the 100px from the wrapper div.

if you have:

adsf

```
#wrapper {
  height:400px;
}
.container
{
  width:80%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:#eee;
}
```

then you .container will be 200px. 50% of the wrapper.

So you may want to look at the divs "wrapping" your ".container"...