# Fixed Div Height as Percentage of Page Height

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545507/div-height-in-percentage) example to make my div consistent to the page / screen resolution. Even this looks very simple but I dont know why its not working with me. I did the same in my page but not working.

It shows me div.container 1066.39 x 18 in page inspect when I mouse hover on container div.

My page source is bellow.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .container
        {
            width:80%;
            height:50%;
            background-color:green;
        }
        html,body {
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            adsf
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.

-------- EDITED MY ACTUAL PAGE IS BELLOW --- WHICH DOESNT TAKE EFFECT.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CostParameter2.aspx.cs" Inherits="JobCosting.CostParameter2" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/footerControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="footerControl" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body,
        form {
          height: 100%;
        }
        .containermain {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color: green;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- page content -->
    <div class="containermain">
    <div class="right_col" role="main">
        <div class="row">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="title_left mytitle_left">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="myform-group">
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 form-group pull-left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameSearch" Height="32px" MaxLength="100" placeholder="Search by Cost Parameter Name" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 form-group myform-group pull-right" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 8px">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" CssClass="btn btn-success input-sm" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" runat="server" Text="Search" />
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdd" CssClass="btn btn-primary input-sm" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" runat="server">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    Add&nbsp;
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPrint" CssClass="btn btn-info input-sm" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" runat="server">
                                    <span class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    Print&nbsp;
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="myx_panel">
                                    <div class="x_content myx_content">
                                        <div style="height: 30px; margin: 0">
                                            <table id="tblHeader" class="table table-condensed"
                                                style="background-color: #2A3F54; color: white; border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="text-align: left">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCostName" runat="server" Text="Cost Parameter Name"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" style="text-align: left">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPercentage" runat="server" Text="(%)age"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" style="text-align: left">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server" Text="Active"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-pull-1" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 30px">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblOption" runat="server" Text="Option"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="overflow: auto;">
                                            <asp:GridView ID="grdCost" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" ShowHeader="false"
                                                DataKeyNames="CostID"
                                                OnRowCommand="grdCost_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdCost_RowDataBound"
                                                BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="1" GridLines="None" Font-Size="Small">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CostName">
                                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"></ItemStyle>
                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Percentage" DataFormatString="{0:0}%">
                                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></ItemStyle>
                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Active">
                                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></ItemStyle>
                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Option">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" CommandName="editRecord"
                                                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CostID") + "," + Eval("CostName") + "," + Eval("Percentage") + "," + Eval("Active")%>' runat="server">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="padding-left:30px"></span>
                                                            </asp:LinkButton>

                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="deleteRecord"
                                                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CostID") + "," + Eval("CostName")%>' runat="server">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-pull-1"></ItemStyle>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>

                                                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                    <%--Add Record Area--%>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 form-group myform-group pull-left">
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCostID" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCostName" Height="32px" MaxLength="100" CssClass="form-control myform-control input-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <label>Cost Parameter Name</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mycol-md-4px mycol-xs-4px form-group myform-group pull-left">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPercentage" Height="32px" MaxLength="2" CssClass="form-control myform-control input-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <label>(%)age</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mycol-md-4px mycol-xs-4px form-group myform-group pull-left">
                                                <div style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 4px">
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div style="margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 4px">
                                                    <label>Active</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-group myform-group pull-right" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 8px">
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn btn-success input-sm" OnClick="btnSave_Click" runat="server">
                                        <span class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        Save
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" CssClass="btn btn-danger input-sm" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: -5px">
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 form-group myform-group pull-left">
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCostName"
                                                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtCostName"
                                                    ForeColor="Red"
                                                    ValidationGroup="vCost"
                                                    Display="Dynamic" Text="Cost Parameter Name is required.">
                                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvCostName" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Cost Parameter Name is already exist."
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtCostName"
                                                    ForeColor="Red"
                                                    OnServerValidate="txtCostName_Validate" Display="Dynamic">
                                                </asp:CustomValidator>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="mycol-md-4px mycol-xs-4px form-group myform-group pull-left">
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPercentage"
                                                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtPercentage"
                                                    ForeColor="Red"
                                                    ValidationGroup="vCost"
                                                    Display="Dynamic" Text="%">
                                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                                <asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID="rvPercentage"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtPercentage"
                                                    ForeColor="Red"
                                                    Type="Integer" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="99"
                                                    ValidationGroup="vCost"
                                                    ErrorMessage="1-99" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: -35px">
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 form-group myform-group pull-left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="right_col myright_col_footer" role="main">
            <uc1:footerControl runat="server" ID="footerControl" />
        </div>


    </div>
    <!-- /page content -->
    </div>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `#form1` selector to make it works :

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
}

#form1
{
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/np9hgt6u/1/)

Comment: I edited my question with actual page. please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the parent elements should have a height set. Your form element does not have a height set, so the browser is unable to calculate `80%` of unknown height. Set a height for the form:

```css
html,
body,
form {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank for immediate reply. What if I am using masterpage. I have a actually a long page html which I have to settle the height for diff. screen resolution.

Comment: You need to set a height for all parent elements to use `%`. You can use  classes like `.full-height{ height:100%;}` and add it to all parent elements from your master page...

Comment: Can you see my edited question please. I have to fix all pages in my project to effect the different screen  resolutions. :( please help me.