# CSS: width/height attribute respond only to px (not %)

Tags: css

I want to create a red square on in the webpage.

When I write the following html element:

```
<div style="{'background': 'red', 'table-layout': 'fixed', 'width': '**10%**','height' : '**10%**'}"
```

I get a white webpage.

However, when I replace '%' with 'px' and write:

```
<div style="{'background': 'red', 'table-layout': 'fixed', 'width': '**10px**','height' : '**10px**'}"
```

I get a small red square at the corner of the screen. Probably, I use the percent feature wrong. Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: You can find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545507/div-height-in-percentage

Answer (score 4):

```html
<div class="parent" style="width: 100%; height: 500px">
  <div style="width: 10%; height: 10%; background: red"></div>
 </div>
```

i think you need to have a parent which your percentage width and height would base.

Answer (score 0):

When you use percent you define size of object as a percent of the parent. If the parent of your div has a small size e.g. 100px x 100px than setting up your div to 10% width and 10% height will end up with having a div in size 10px x 10px (as this is 10% of parent size).

Make sure the parent size of your div is what you want. Best way is to use Developer Tools build in into the browsers.

Comment: so whenever I use %, do I always have to start with the <html> element and define it to be 100%, and then define all of its offspring ?

Comment: Of course not. Parent is not always html element (in fact you should not style `html` but `body` instead). Parent is an element that contains your div. How the parent is styles and position is only up to you (e.g. it can be positioned `fixed` which will not depend on your body size, etc.).

Comment: when I defined: 
"body { width: 100%; height: 100%}", it didn't work. Only when I wrote: "html. body {  width: 100%; height: 100% }", I got the red square. So... I think it means that we must start with the <html> tag.

Answer (score 0):

'%' need ah position: try this

```html
<div style="position:absolute;background: red;table-layout: fixed;width:10%;height:10%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use % as width and height. First you need some outher div with px.

```
Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/JakubL/sjtcvwdr/
```

Outer div has 1920px height and 1440px width so div-test, (your red square) div will have 192px height and 144px width.

Comment: In theory, this may answer OP's question, but per site's rule, you need to post code here and use link as a reference or demo. Please write your code here or this post will be removed soon