# How do I use % (not vh) height units on a div whose parent is the body element?

Tags: html, css, window

When I set up simple HTML template and add a div to the body.  When I set the width to 50% the div is then 50% of the window / body element. When I set the height to 50% nothing happens, and if i had an H1 tag to the div height it just defaults to height of the div to that of the H1 tag.

Is there anyway to use % values to simply make the div 50% of the window height *without* using vh units, or is the only alternative to either use vh units, or add an absolute height value i.e. 2000px?

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Video Demo</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
background: #e6e6e6;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
```

Any explanation or tips greatly appreciated.

Emily,

Comment: make sure you body and html tags have a height set on them too - percentage heights only work if all tags up to the html have a percentage height on them, (or a direct parent has a fixed height on it) - so add `html, body {height:100%; box-sizing:border-box;}` and your code should work

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545507/div-height-in-percentage