# style.height doesnt work javascript

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

i want to make the map'e height is auto with the device's screen...
but when i change the style.height to auto, 100%, screen.height, the map is disappear...
how to make the height is auto?
this is my code...

script.js

```
$('#home').live('pagecreate',function(){
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.width=screen.width;
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.height="20em";
});
```

in index.html i just called

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    *my header*
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #map_canvas for first, not map_canvas

Comment: if i use #map_canvas, the script will not work...thats why i didnt use #

Comment: Does your js debugger agree with you? try $('#map_canvas').css('height','auto');

Comment: yup...its work perfectly without #...

i hv tried $('#map_canvas').css('height','auto');
its still the same with use screen.height...the map is dissappear...but when i set the height to "20em" it works...

Comment: Probably there are some other rules to be considered for that element. Gl

Comment: have map_canvas some content in itself?

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery you can do as below:
instead of this:

```
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.width=screen.width;
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.height="20em";
```

you can use:

```
$("#map_canvas").css({
    'width':screen.width,
    'height':"20em"
});
```

Comment: thank you very much....it works...i want height is auto...so i change the height to "screen.height" without "...but the format is like that.....

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/krcfX/2/):
I think your problem is related to css not to javascript.
The % height you want to set will be based on the parent height, so if the parent is empty, the 100% of 0 will be 0: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/2357192)

code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
<style>
#map_canvas{
    background-color:#00F;
    }
#cont{
    background:#F00;
    height:200px;
    }
</style>
<button onClick="doit1()">Click me to put something in map_canvas</button>
<button onClick="doit()">Click me to make the height 100%</button>

<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    *my header*
    </div>

    <div id="cont" data-role="content">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$('#home').live('pagecreate',function(){
$('#map_canvas').css('height','auto');
});
function doit(){
    $('#map_canvas').css('height','100%');
    }
function doit1(){
    $('#map_canvas').html('a')
    }
</script>
</html>
```