# Custom CSS (Qualtrics)

Tags: javascript, html, css, survey, qualtrics

I am new to custom CSS. My boss wants me to add Custom CSS in Qualtrics(under Look and Feel/Advanced). Everything seems to format fine in the edit preview window, but on the actual survey page the formatting for many elements is not applied:images are original size, div's are not visible, etc.

I'm assuming this has something to do with individual browsers, something I must specify such as a webkit thing, but I don't understand it too well. Here is a simple piece of my code(images are my biggest concern):

HTML:

```
<img id="bing" src="http://i39.tinypic.com/16kc3k0.jpg">;
```

CSS:

```
#bing{
    display:block;
    width:15%;
    height:15%;
    }
```

I know there's some attributes such as

```
-webkit-appearance: cover;
 -moz-appearance: cover;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read this [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

> "If you want to make the div height a percentage of the viewport
>   height, every ancestor of the div, including  and , have
>   to have height: 100%, so there is a chain of explicit percentage
>   heights down to the div."

if you are having problem with the tool, try to add inline style by writing

```
<img id="bing" style="display:block; width:15%; height:15%; " src="http://i39.tinypic.com/16kc3k0.jpg">;
```

EDIT: One should really the styling in the CSS. figure out your tool to do so and find out any other problem that is not letting you do so..

Comment: I don't believe it is HTML 5. The way it works is you copy and paste the HTML into the header and put the custom CSS into a separate window. I don't know how to add HTML to the CSS box or I would.   http://oi41.tinypic.com/3309zq0.jpg

Comment: if you are having problem with the tool, try to add inline style by writing as edited above in my answer. please mark as helpful if it helps.

Comment: That did work! However I would really like to do it without inline. Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't used that tool actually.  but I think you can do that by clicking `add custom CSS` and write the `#bing{...}` there. please mark my answers and comments as helpful :) upvotes. thanks.

Comment: Yes I marked it :) Thanks. I added in the code there, it's the CSS I showed above. I don't understand why it isn't working!! :(

Comment: Figured it out. It was ignoring my file because of a comment on the top! Well that was ridiculous.. thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to know that you figured it out.

Comment: @MrLister Kindly up vote my answer because I have edited my answer to remove mistake and It did help out the guy in trouble. thanks.