# firefox css max-width and max-height inside max-height div

Tags: css, firefox

I have a div with max-height and an image inside it, that should use max-width:100% and max-height:100%. In chromium, this works, but firefox uses only max-width and ignores max-heigth.

```
div#overlaycontent{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:auto; 
}

div#pic{
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:right;
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 250px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 250px);
  width: calc(100% - 250px); 
  max-height:90%;
}

img#zoompic{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

How can I achieve that firefox will use both? max-width *and* max-height ?

Comment: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qx75g/

Comment: Ahhh.... now I see. ```max-height``` is not enough for firefox. Set ```height``` and it works as expected. Thats because only ```height``` of inner calculates a real height for the ```max-height``` of the image. http://jsfiddle.net/wd9rP/

Comment: The problem is, below the orange div, I have comments. So if the image is small or the browser window is narrow (responsive css), there is empty space between picture and comments. That's why I wanted to use max-height.. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css . To use the ```max-height``` attribute you'll have to set the height of a parent container. Otherwise the browser don't know how to calculate the height (height of what?).

Comment: Like in the fiddle, I have these heights: body(100%)->(div(100%)->div(max.50%)->div(max.100%).. which works in chromium (!), but not in firefox. it seems, firefox doesn't like the two max-heights. probably it does not accept "percent of percent"

Answer (score 5):

The [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) describes `max-height` with percentage as follows:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as none.

This description is also used with `height` and percentage values. So if you want to use the `max-height` property you'll have to set the image or the parent container to a specific pixel size. Maybe if you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your problem we can show you other solutions without `max-height`.

---

EDIT//
Now with the given JSFiddle, this is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/wd9rP/