# Percentage of height not working for portrait screen orientation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height, orientation

I am trying to set percentage for 2 div elements(main and header) contained in the body of html. The problem is that this is not working(the height percentages appearing are wrong) when my screen orientation is portrait. Examples dimensions i am checking are the below:

320x480

320x568

600x800

768x1024

800x1280

I use [viewport resizer](http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/) to check my code.

HTML code:

```
<body>
<header>

<div id="title">
Just a title
</div>

</header>

<main>
Main div element here
</main>

</body>
```

CSS code:

```
html, body{
    background-color:#A8F000;
    height:100%;
    }

header{
    background-color:#F80012;
    height:25%;
    }

main{
    background-color:#009E8E;
    height:70%;
    }
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of line for the `header` height, but you're also using DOM element names that aren't standard. Why not name them `header` and `main` as `div` with IDs?

Comment: Unfortunately for me the viewportresizer takes longer than 2 seconds as I can't seem to find the download button ... WTF?!? :D

Comment: you have to bookmark viewportresizer

Comment: What do you mean by **not working**? That is an awfully general description for a problem - can you describe it in greater detail? (like, is the height computed wrongly and etc)

Comment: i added that the appearing heights are wrong. as simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: [viewport](http://html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/)

```
header{
    background-color:#F80012;
    height:25%;
}
```

Add ;

Comment: Edited. This not the issue. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: thanks for the link. can you tell me which specific part of this link will help me in my problem?

Comment: @Dchris [viewport example](http://html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/)

Comment: can you add a short explanation of how viewport will save my day to your answer? it is working

Comment: This answer would be more useful to other searchers if you add your content to the body of the answer rather than only including it in the comment trail.

Comment: you tell me? @Palpatim

Comment: @MeathGrebenshchikov I think that yes he is referring to you. Just edit your answer including  your comment regarding viewport and some explanation

Answer (score 1):

It is working perfectly fine. Take a look at fiddle

```
html, body{
    background-color:#A8F000;
    height:100%;
    }

header{
    background-color:#F80012;
    height:20%;
    }

main{
    background-color:#009E8E;
    height:80%;
    }
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7EEMB/