# height property inherit percentage as is?

Tags: html, css, height

simple noob question, assuming i have this:

```
<div style="height:90%; display:block">
    <div id="second" style="height:inherit">
        <div id="third" style="height:inherit">
        </div
    </div>
</div>
```

Does the third div has a property of 72% height or 90%?

Comment: Ya it has but what u are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can check on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DL6Vj/2/).

Comment: What value did you get when you tried it?

Comment: Only if all the parents have a height set btw. Check this updated version of @Mr_green fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DL6Vj/3/ (see why here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Comment: thank you all, once you see it it's very clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it inherits the 90%, but relative to its parent, which is 90% but that, to the child, is like 100%.. oh well you get it :) here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DL6Vj/4/

```
<div style="height:90%; display:block;width:50%;float:left;background:tan">
    <div id="second" style="height:inherit;background:red">
        <div id="third" style="height:inherit;background:pink"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height:73%; display:block;float:left;width:50%;background:green"></div>
```

if compared to the absolute 100% of the body yes, it's a 73% height approx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no, I mean yes, depends from where you look :)

**So it's always 90% the height of it's parent.**

http://jsbin.com/tigod/2/edit

> *Does the third div has a property of 72% height or 90%?*

### 90%

Answer (score 0):

**It'll inherit 90% from the parent.**

As someone suggested in the comments, see the result in the fiddle: it's 90% relative to the parent, which is at the same time about 72% (actually almost 73%) of the body height. (90% of 90% of 90% of page height)