# Two divs bottom div to height adjust with browser window

Tags: html, css, resize

I have a header div and a div underneath it. I need the div underneath the header div to adjust depending on the height of the browser window size.

In CSS, when I add height:100% it creates a scroll bar at the side of the page. When I adjust the percentage of the width, spacing at the bottom of the page constantly changes because it is done with percentages.

I would like the div below the header to always adjust with the window size in height with no spacing at the bottom.

How do I do this?

Here is the Fiddle

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyvf9/)
I am not sure why but in JSFiddle the bottom div is not extending height: 100%

here is the code:
HTML

```
 <div class = "main">
  Header
 </div>
 <div class="left">
  Bottom Div
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
width:100%;
height:60px;
border: solid;
}

.left {
height: 100%;
width: 300px;
border:solid;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use something like this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/dyvf9/2/)

html:

```
<div class = "main">
     Header
</div>
<div class="left">
    Bottom Div
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box; 
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
} 
body {
    padding:60px 0 0 0; /* 60 — header height*/
    margin:0;
}
.main,
.left {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.main {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    margin-top: -60px;  /* 60 — header height*/
}

.left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options to achieve the layout you would like.

There are plenty of answers that address your problem from this similar question:
[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1)

However, here is my solution:
Just change your CSS a bit

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
} 

.main {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border: solid;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    border:solid;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

The box-sizing will prevent the padding-top and the borders from pushing the dimensions outside the browser window. The body,html height: 100%; is needed to allow other items to be 100% height (why your fiddle wouldn't work).

Answer (score 0):

CSS allows you to do some basic math, so the following would help you:

Given that your header has a fixed height of 60px:

```
.left {
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Edit: you also have some extra padding and borders that you might want to take into consideration while calculating. Although I'm not a big fan of hard-coding values like that.

Comment: This was a possible solution for me, but did not come out exactly the way I wanted it to, but thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your style sheet

CSS

```
.left {
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
border:solid;
}
```

Refer link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css