# Jquery css is not working on document.ready

Tags: jquery, css, function, document-ready

There is one line in my jquery code not working after the document.ready function.
The others do work.

The same line does work in a window.resize function.
I hop you can help me:
I added a comment after the line that is not working

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>
            Made in 030
        </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" />
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                        // hover
            $(function() {

                var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
                    $mainNav = $("menu ul");

                $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
                var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

                $magicLine
                    .width($("menu ul li.active").width())
                    .css("left", $("menu ul li.active a").position().left)
                    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
                    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

                $("menu ul li a").hover(function() {
                    $el = $(this);
                    leftPos = $el.position().left;
                    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
                    $magicLine.stop().animate({
                        left: leftPos,
                        width: newWidth
                    },500);
                }, function() {
                    $magicLine.stop().animate({
                        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
                    },500);    
                });
            });

            $('.menu_container').css('height',$('body').width()/11);
            $('menu ul li a').css('font-size',$('body').width()/85);
            $('#magic-line').css('margin-top',$('body').width()/11 - 10);//This line is not working
            $('.logo img').css('height',$('body').width()/11-15);
            $('.logo').css('height',$('body').width()/11);

            var outerHeight = $('menu ul li').height();
            var innerHeight = $('menu ul li a').height();
            $('menu ul li a').css('margin-top', (outerHeight - innerHeight)/2);

            var outerWidth = $('menu').width();
            var innerWidth = $('.logo').width();
            $('.logo_container').css('margin-left', (outerWidth - innerWidth)/2);



        })
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.menu_container').css('height',$('body').width()/11);
            $('menu ul li a').css('font-size',$('body').width()/85);
            $('#magic-line').css('top',$('body').width()/11 - 10);
            $('.logo img').css('height',$('body').width()/11-15);
            $('.logo').css('height',$('body').width()/11);

            var outerHeight = $('menu ul li').height();
            var innerHeight = $('menu ul li a').height();
            $('menu ul li a').css('margin-top', (outerHeight - innerHeight)/2);

            var outerWidth = $('menu').width();
            var innerWidth = $('.logo').width();
            $('.logo_container').css('margin-left', (outerWidth - innerWidth)/2);
        })

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="menu_container">
                <menu>
                    <ul class="left_menu" >
                        <li class="left" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="left" ><a href="#">Over</a></li>
                        <li class="left"><a href="#">Probeerlijst</a></li>
                        <li class="logo_container">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <img src="img/logo.png" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="right active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="right"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                        <li class="right"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </menu>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: haven't tested it, but what line doesn't work? did you leave that out or did I miss it?

Comment: @Benjamin I did load the library, but i didn't show it here.
But now i did.

Comment: @Todd There is a comment after the line.
It is:
$('#magic-line').css('margin-top',$('body').width()/11 - 10);

Comment: You should ***really*** consider to use CSS media queries...

Comment: Yep, I see the whole file when I try to edit it. Will remove -1.

Comment: Where is the `#magic-line`in your HTML code??

Comment: two doc ready nested, is it required? also you have a wrong DTD at top.

Comment: @A.Wolff, I want it flowing and not in steps.

Comment: @JesseUilenreef So just use percentage in some CSS rules. Seriously, you are just asking for trouble with this kind of unmaintainable code

Comment: @A.Wolff,
Setting height in percentages in CSS?

Comment: @JesseUilenreef Why not? e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/1414562

Comment: Regarding your issue, this is because you are nesting ready handler twice for adding `magic_line` element, `$(function() {...});` is shorthand for ready handler, so just remove it if you want still to deal with so much unreadable kind of code

Comment: @A.Wolff Oh Thank you, i really never heard of that vh an vw option.
Thanks!

Comment: @JesseUilenreef so I feel like you should add `#magic-line` directly to markup rather than through script; as it is, I haven't found any reason to add it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to save the value in a variable first. Then add parentheses to get the right order of precedence. This will work.

```
var value = $('body').width() / (11 - 10);
$('#magic-line').css('margin-top', value); //This line is not working

console.log(value);
```

Comment: He has the `id=magic-line` in his code. Check this line from his post: > `$mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that the `$('#magic-line')` is empty at your not working line.

You need to add some `window.setTimeout` to your code to make sure, that it runs at the right time. (after you append it)

Watch this:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('.menu_container').css('height',$('body').width()/11);
    $('menu ul li a').css('font-size',$('body').width()/85);
    console.log($('#magic-line'));
    $('#magic-line').css('margin-top',$('body').width()/11 - 10); // this one is not working
    $('.logo img').css('height',$('body').width()/11-15);
    $('.logo').css('height',$('body').width()/11);

    var outerHeight = $('menu ul li').height();
    var innerHeight = $('menu ul li a').height();
    $('menu ul li a').css('margin-top', (outerHeight - innerHeight)/2);

    var outerWidth = $('menu').width();
    var innerWidth = $('.logo').width();
    $('.logo_container').css('margin-left', (outerWidth - innerWidth)/2);
}, 1);
```

I just added the first and last line. And a `console.log`. With the `window.setTimeout` the log gets the wanted element, without the `window.setTimeout` the log is empty.