# CSS : height 50% not working

Tags: html, css

[image]I know this question has been asked many time here however I couldn't manage to find a solution to my problem.

I'm adding a webpage to a complex website with tons of css. I'm trying to apply a `height:50%;` to a div, it doesn't work (The data are wrapped together).

With my research I understood it's because the parent element isn't set at `height:100%;` so I tried setting html and body to 100% : No change.

Using `position: absolute;` make it works but then it ignores the header size and write my text over it.

With the IE debugger I found the parent div, setting it at `height: 100%` doesn't work.

How can I find what parent CSS element I should set at 100% ?

Comment: Unless you include your HTML and CSS in the question, we can't help you.

Comment: You've set the parent div to 100%, but 100% of what? what height does it's parent have?

Comment: I setted height:100% to every parent I could find.
I uploaded a picture of code & edited my post, please let me know if you need more info :)

Comment: @IggY If you would, please include the *actual code* in your post, not just a partial screenshot.

Comment: if the panels are floating it's probably that they have not real height in px, try to add `class="clearfix"` to div  parent

Comment: Read this question for more info about expand proper width and height on floated divs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix

Comment: @mgamon doesn't solve the problem :s

Comment: provide your html and css code to aim you put on fiddle and share link http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @mgamon I manage to make it work on a little snippet, so a fiddle wouldn't help, there is 20+ css files and I'm not allowed to share them :s I understand it can prevent you to help me, sorry for that

Comment: I'm sorry for that but isn't posible to help you for now with this info. I'm sure that the issue it's produced by a floating elements that are not properly expanded. If you are using Bootstrap it's more probably check with the inspector element what div have no height  =)

Comment: @mgamon my <body> has the good size, but under it there is a <div id="body>" who has size 0, although I gave him the property height:100% in css. -- The size i4m talking about are the one indicated by the google chroée debugger when I put my mouse over the div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71187/discussion-between-mgamon-and-iggy).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Answer (score 0):

if the parent is `100%` but in reality the height is `0px` then the `<div>` with `50%` is half of 0 == 0.

Try setting the parent `background:red` the the 50% div `background:blue` to aid in debugging.

Comment: This isn't an answer.  This is a comment and should be posted as such under the original question.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, applying a background color doesn't change anything so I guess it's the right path to find the solution. If I change height :100% by 100px in the parent then the color appear. Is there a clever way I can find where problematic height = 0px is ?

Comment: I know is Crome you can inspect element and down the bottom you get a nice box with dimensions etc.  I have also found that height: n% is a bit odd.  can you not us `px`.  alternatively us js to get the height and half it?