# HTML image height (in %) does not change?

Tags: html

example:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_height
I can change the width in terms of % or px but,
I can only change the height in terms of px and not % (you can experiment by changing height to a % and seeing it does not change).
This is just an example but I am wondering how you change height in terms of %?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use percentage `height` in a `div`, the parent objects of it have to have explicit `height` property. 
Unlike `width`, website with fixed heights will bring you problems.

My advice: don't use percentage `height` in HTML. Instead, try `padding`

```
#mydiv{
   padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css) for more info.

Comment: yeah, the 'See here for more info' did help for sure. The div will give its height bounds and then I can set the height to a % of those bounds.



            <style>
              #mydiv{
             height: 100px; width: 50%; background: red;
                }
</style>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="50%" height="50%"
</div>
</body>

Comment: Even then it does not scale properly, but I guess there is nothing that can be done.
edit: not sure how adding adding padding on the bottom helps

Comment: edit:
                    #mydiv {
                              height:50vh; background:red; 
               width:50%;
                        }    works

Answer (score 0):

it is working just fine.
just edit like width="200%"

img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="200%" height="400%"

see height="400%"