# Full screen background slideshow messing up responsive sticky footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position a sticky footer in its place but my full screen background slideshow somehow moves it up under the content. I am following a responsive sticky footer tutorial from this site [Sticky footer tutorial](http://geekgirllife.com/responsive-sticky-footer-woes-and-fixes/) where the page content is set as `display:table` and the footer is set as a `display:table-row`. This works great until I introduce my slideshow to the picture. Once I remove the slideshow the sticky footer works!. Is there a way to fix this problem and keep the sticky footer at the bottom?. You can see the problem live here [link with the problem](http://www.rajeevthomas.com/).

My CSS and HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> HTML Structure</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-bgstretcher-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <style>
        html {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        }

        body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }

        .site {
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        }

        .site-content {
        width: 100%;
        color:#FBF7F7;
        text-align:center;
        background:#2DEFEC repeat;
        height:200px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        .site-footer {
        display: table-row;
        height: 1px;
        background:#2A1818 repeat;
        width:100%;
        color:#FBF7F7;
        text-align:center;
        }

        .bgstretcher-area {
        text-align: left;
        }
        .bgstretcher {
        background: black;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        }
        .bgstretcher,
        .bgstretcher ul,
        .bgstretcher li {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        }
        .bgstretcher ul,
        .bgstretcher li {
        position: absolute;
        }
        .bgstretcher ul,
        .bgstretcher li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        }
        /*  Compatibility with old browsers  */
        .bgstretcher {
        _position: absolute;
        }
        .bgs-description-pane {
        display: block;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10000;
        padding: 15px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 14px;
        }       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
            <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner"></header>
            <div id="content" class="site-content">I am just some content!</div>
            <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">I am a footer</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
        $("body").bgStretcher({
        images: ["/1-1.jpg", "/2-1.jpg"], 
        imageWidth: 1024,
        imageHeight: 768
        }); 
        }); 
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a complete table layout in order to have the *sticky footer* to work properly. Check out the following **simplified demo** and read the comments inline, see if you're missing anything important.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8tqov1a/)

```css
html, body, #page {
    height: 100%; /*make the elements to cover the whole page height*/
    margin: 0;
}
#page {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.site-header,
.site-content,
.site-footer {
    display: table-row; /*for all the three sections*/
}
.site-content {
    height: 100%; /*push header and footer to their minimum height */
    background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">header</header>
    <div id="content" class="site-content">I am just some content!</div>
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">I am a footer</footer>
</div>
```

**Update**, that jQuery plugin OP's using, added some container divs around `#page`, so either set them all to `height:100%;`, or simply set `#page{height:100vh;}` revised [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8tqov1a/1/).

Comment: Pangloss, thank you for your answer. Yes the sticky footer works but only when the slideshow script is not present in the code. As soon as I add the slideshow script and its CSS the footer messes up. I have updated the link with your simplified complete table. But as you can see unfortunately the footer is up on the top. Thanks again...

Comment: Try this `#page{height:100vh;}`, it you can't use viewport units, you'll need to use browser dev tools to find all the parent elements of `#page` and set them all to `height:100%`, obviously that plugin added many div contianers.

Comment: !That works! Thank you so much for your help! I am newbie so I am trying to understand this, can you tell me why this works? Why vh works vs 100% on #page ?

Comment: That is a very common question, i.e. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css).

Comment: Accepted as correct answer. I found and changed the heights to 100% on parental elements of #page and it works. Thanks for the link I appreciate you taking the time so that I can learn further!