# html5 image header not showing

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with my website, I want to have a picture named banner.png in the header, I am supposed to use header and not div, since this is html5.

this is the index.html file

```
<!-- HTML 5 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Erling's website</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<header>
</header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the stylesheet

```
header {
    background-image: url("img/banner.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
}
```

I do find the picture when inspect element but it looks like the height is not working.

```css
header {
  /*DEMO*/background-color: red;
  background-image: url("img/banner.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML 5 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Erling's website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<header>
</header>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 15% of what? If you don't set a height on the `html` & `body` elements it won't work.

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: See this post: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Question to yourself: 15% of what?

If you use the developer tools of your browser and select the `html` or `body` tag from the opened window, you will see that the html and body do not have any height. 15% of 0 = 0, so the header must have a fixed height,  for example: `230px`, or you can add this style in your CSS file:

```css
Html,body {position:relative;height:100%;}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10349779)

Comment: İ just want help him but my english :/ i dont criticize

Answer (score 0):

For the above percentage height to work with your header add

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Or change the height on the header to padding bottom.

```
header {
    padding-bottom: 30%;
}
```

Comment: There is a height on the header...15%

Comment: aha! i see that now... Then he needs to add `body, html {height: 100%;}`

Comment: Indeed...I commented to that effect.

Comment: % height does not work if the parent element doesn't have a fixed hight

Comment: nope stil not there, `position: absolute` breaks it

Answer (score 0):

The above answer will solve the issue, but if you for any reason want to set the height as % in your header, you need to set the size of the html to 100% so that the header gets 15% of it.

```
html{
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [view units](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-viewport-units/), `vh` for view height and `vw` for view width [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/y2ncdkh0/)

```
header {
    height: 15vh; /* represents 15% of the view height, 100vh is 100% of the height*/
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `height: 15%;`, You mean the header should take `15%` of it's parent. This will have no effect since you haven't set the height of the parent which is the `body`. You either have to give the body height or else use `pixels` instead of `percentage`

```
header {
    height:100px; /*You can specify your size*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution: *note that also width was not working*

```css
    header {
      background-color: red; /* red for DEMO */
      background-image: url("img/banner.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 15%;
      position: absolute;
      width: inherit;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100%; /* fix height*/
      width: 100%; /* fix width */
      margin: 0; /* fix width, or margin: 0 -5px; in header {} */
    }
```

```html
<!-- HTML 5 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Erling's website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<header>
</header>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Another Post about this: [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css), it also mentions the use of `height: 15vh;`

Comment: make shure to flag the answer as "accepted" if your question was solved ;) any maybe give it a *up* for motivation :D

Answer (score 0):

**`<header>` element position in html**

It is invalid html to have a `<header>` element as a child of the `<html>` element. Your html is not valid accord to [HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html).

You must move the `<header>` element to be inside the `<body>` element.

Part of what is happening here is that because the `<header>` element comes before the `<body>` element, the document model is forced to create a `<body>` element to contain `<header>` so your `<body>` element is being ignored.

Move your `<header>` tag to be within `<body>` and go from there.

Once that is fixed, then you can work on the sizing issue. Because the `<body>` element has nothing in it, the width will be 0. You can force it to fill the frame by giving body a width of 100% and your header image will work.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want the header to be 15% of the height of the visible window then change height to use the `vh` (viewport height) unit which is a percentage of the height of the visible window.

```
header {
    [...]
    height: 15vh;
}
```