# Make google maps fill height

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using this [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) to include Google Maps in my Ionic app.
It works fine, but I would like it to fill the entire height that is still available beneath the header.

I'm only able to give it a height in px, like so:

```
.angular-google-map-container { height: 200px;}
```

The moment I change it to %, it doesn't show the map anymore.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Post your view, js and css code in here or on a Fiddle/Plunk to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work using:

```
.angular-google-map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you are using a percentage you have to ask yourself ["Percentage of what?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/1980659)...  Since you didn't provide the whole code it is impossible to answer you perfectly.

By using `.angular-google-map-container { height: 200px;}` you are forcing all parents container to increase their size to fit the 200px height.  That's why it works.

A dumb fix would be using [view port](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) height value.  Something like :

```
height: 80vh;
```

Which is 80% of the view port height.