# Secondary Css document having no effect on related div with id

Tags: html, css

On my site for whatever reason the CSS is refusing to take effect on the html and as far as I can tell its only from that specific sheet, my global one seems to be working fine.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Anise Technologies</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?php include 'global/includes/header.php'?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include 'global/includes/nav.php'?>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="slider">
            </div>
            <div id="promo-tiles">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php include 'global/includes/footer.php'?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document FOR HOME PAGE ONLY*/
.main {
    height: 100%;
}
.slider {
    height: 60%;
}
.promo-tiles {
    height: 30%;
}
.promo-tiles-ul{
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
.promo-tiles li{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please provide HTML/CSS sample. Unless you php  is totally broken what you use to render the page makes no difference to CSS.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the PHP code is working perfect and the html and CSS or right there

Comment: Than remove unrelated PHP references/tag from code (I've removed all unrelated "stuck here" / "starting for fun" text from the post, consider keeping it that way unless you find that "stuck" somehow related to your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the class selector. Change them to the id selector

```
#main {
    height: 100%;
}
#slider {
    height: 60%;
}
#promo-tiles {
    height: 30%;
}
#promo-tiles ul{
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#promo-tiles li{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't to cry but thanks :P and for whatever reason the percent isn't working with heights only EMs are not sure why

Comment: If you want to have a height as a percentage, the element you are trying to set the height as a percentage must have a parent element with a fixed height. Have a look at the answer here for a more detailed explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css

Comment: that worked thanks! And for what ever reason the list-style: none is doing nothing either...

Comment: The correct syntax should be `list-style-type: none;` I'll edit the answer.

Comment: ok I'm using sublime text for the first time so I'm not exactly used to the differences between it an dreamweaver thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

You are using classes in CSS and expect it somehow find elements by ID. Pick one and it would work fine:

```
#main {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or with classes

```
<div class="main">
```

Comment: I wasn't to cry but thanks :P and for whatever reason the percent isn't working with heights only EMs are not sure why

Comment: @user3784444 getting height 100 on HTML elements  is interesting exercise, but that is not point of your post from what I can tell... (You really need to know 100% of what - if you clarify your goal you may be able to find existing questions on that or ask  new one).