# CSS calc() not working when parent element contains height:100%

Tags: css

**Here are my code:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>

.box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.test {
    background: blue;
    height: calc(100% - 47px);
}
```

When I set height: 100% then calc() not working properly. But when I set height:500px then calc() works fine.

How it's possible? and how can I solve this bug?

Comment: To set a percentage height, its parent element must have an explicit height. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/1091308)

Comment: @Niyoko Yuliawan Thank you. But I have make responsive layout using calc() in this case how can I use explicit height? and have you any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: @RkinfotechPhp even with `height: 100%` it should work. Are you sure the grand parent or higher precendence element has height?

Comment: @Mr_Green I have set <html> and <body> to height:100%

Comment: working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/9uoyko83/