# HERE Maps React Component shows up as empty

Tags: reactjs, here-api, heremaps

I am attempting to make a small web app with React that involves a map. I'm using the HERE Maps react component (this is non-negotiable) but I'm having trouble getting the map to show up. I'm not sure if it's the Key or my understanding of React (which is small), that's causing the issue.

**Map Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import HEREMap from "react-here-maps";

@connect((store) => {
  return {

  };
})
export default class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.info(HEREMap);

    const style = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%"
    };

    return <div style={style}>
      <h1>Hello HERE</h1>
      <HEREMap
            appId="<ID>"
            appCode="<CODE>"
            center={{ lat: 51.5, lng: 0 }}
            zoom={14}
      />
    </div>
  };
};
```

**Main**

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"

import Map from "./components/Map"
import Layout from "./components/Layout"
import store from "./store"

const app = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Map />
    </Provider>, app);
```

Comment: I think that component `hereMaps` should be `HereMaps` - first char has uppercase

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen this, but there is a tutorial on the HERE Developer Blog for React.js, https://developer.here.com/blog/here-with-react-location-based-todo-app

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this in you code listing:

```
const style = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%"
};
```

A common problem is that the height of a block element like `<div>` defaults to the height of the block's content.  By specifying it as a percentage like 100%, it will be the height of the element's parent which if it's just an empty container with no content will have a height of 0 and therefore not be visible.

The answers in [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css) might be helpful for finding alternatives like setting the height of the body element.

There may also be something else going on as the *react-here-maps* package has a few issues, but you said that wasn't negotiable.  For anybody else looking for a more standalone demonstration, the  [Use HERE Interactive Maps with ReactJS to Pick a Theme](https://developer.here.com/blog/use-here-interactive-maps-with-reactjs-to-pick-a-theme) might be helpful.  In the source example there, the height is fixed at 400px.