# Is there a way to expand page or container based on content?

Tags: html, css, layout

Is there a way to expand a page or container based on content divs?  Do you need to specify the height in all divs in order for them to expand to the desired size?  I am not understanding how to expand divs.

```css
html{
        height:100%;
        
    }
    body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: grey;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    
    }
    #container{
        height:90%;
        width:80%;
        margin:auto;
        border-style: solid;
        
    }
    #header{
       height:8%;
       width:100%;
    
    }
    #head_wrap{
        height:90%;
        width:100%;
        margin:auto;
    }
    #content{
        height:70%;
        width:80%;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

```html
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>basic</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="container">
           <div id="header">
               <div id="head_wrap">
                   
               </div>
          
           
           </div>
               <div id="content">
                 
               </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The default behavior of div is to Occupy height based on the occupied children heights.

Comment: Never set the height of the body in percentage, see here for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow` css rule to expand **container** based on **content**:

```
#container, #content{
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow` to hide overflowing content.

```
#content{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Use `overflow-wrap` to break overflowing content

```
#content{
     overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never set the height of the body in percentage, see here for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css) replace your body tag with this code

```
body {
    height:100vh; 
}
```