# Why is my div image not appearing inside parent div?

Tags: html, css

I am making an author box.  I want the person's picture at the right of the box while still inside the parent div. Whatever styles I apply, I can't make the picture appear inside the div and on the right smoothly, what is wrong here?

```css
.authorBox {
    background: #222222;
    width: 100%;
    padding:1.5em 2em;
    position: relative;
    border-left:15px solid #d53362;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h5.author {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

h5.authorRole {
    color: #d53362;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

p.authorQuote {
    color:#444;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.personImg1 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(../img/person1.jpeg);
}

.personContainer {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="authorBox">
       <h5 class="author">First Last</h5>
       <h5 class="authorRole">Job role goes here</h5>
       <p class="authorQuote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu erat at nisl laoreet ultrices"</p>
       <div class="personContainer">
            <div class="personImg1"></div>
       </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css

Comment: @DonnieBerry did any of the below work for you? If so, you should click the green checkbox so everyone knows this problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution using flex box.

```css
.authorBox {
  background: #222222;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 15px solid #d53362;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h5.author {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h5.authorRole {
  color: #d53362;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

p.authorQuote {
  color: #444;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.personImg1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(../img/person1.jpeg);
}
```

```html
<div class="authorBox">
  <div class="colContainer">
    <h5 class="author">First Last</h5>
    <h5 class="authorRole">Job role goes here</h5>
    <p class="authorQuote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu erat
      at nisl laoreet ultrices"</p>
  </div>
  <div class="personContainer">
    <div class="personImg1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that puts the image under the text in my box, i need it on the right

Comment: No its on the right. I added a div to wrap you h5 and p. You can run my code the way i posted it both html and css

Comment: @FridayAmeh I believe he is talking about on smaller screen dimensions the image will reflow below the author information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you locating your image properly from your folders? 
Also, you can try this

```
.personImg1 {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background:url("../img/person1.jpeg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;

}
```

Comment: Please use the built in tools for creating code blocks. Back ticks are used for inline code only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a div with no height and width won't be seen, so you div with the background has to have a defined width/height so you can see it.

and you put in the right by positioning it absolute and right:0 or a small amount just to push it from the edge.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.authorBox {
  background: #222222;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 15px solid #d53362;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h5.author {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h5.authorRole {
  color: #d53362;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

p.authorQuote {
  color: #444;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.personContainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 1.5em;
}

.personImg1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
}
```

```html
<div class="authorBox">

  <h5 class="author">First Last</h5>
  <h5 class="authorRole">Job role goes here</h5>
  <p class="authorQuote">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu erat at nisl laoreet ultrices"
  </p>

  <div class="personContainer">
    <div class="personImg1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.personImg1` has `width:100%;` and `height:100%;`, which means it gets the full width and height of its parent container - i.e. relative settings.

But the parent container's only CSS property is `.personContainer { float:right; }` – there are no width or height settings for it, resulting in *zero height* both for this container, the `.personImg1` DIV and therefore also the background-image of `.personImg1`. So you need to assign some width and height to `.personContainer`

Actually you might want to consider to just use a regular `img` tag instead of that `.personImg1` DIV and its background-image...