# Different implementation of Flexbox in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

The following code works as expected in Firefox, but in Chrome, the images become much bigger than the flex container.

```css
.r {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: unset;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
</div>
```

**Firefox**:
[image]

**Chrome**:
[image]

Comment: Try .r { max-width: 100%; height: auto }

Comment: always avoid having the img as flex item, wrap them inside the flex item

Comment: @TemaniAfif but it isn't really a solutiom is it. I want just wondering why there's two different implementations

Comment: What a disappointing outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following code works as expected in Firefox

I disagree with this because for me Chrome is behaving as expected for 2 reasons:

1. You set the width of the image to be `100%` which means 100% of their containing block (container) that is defined by `600px`. So each image will be `600px`
2. The image cannot [shrink past its content size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333) due to the default `min-width` configuration (note that using [`unset` is equivalent to `initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/unset) in this case so it's somehow useless). So the image will be kept at `600px`

If you add `min-width:0` the image will shrink only in width:

```css
.r {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: auto; useless */
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
</div>
```

*the behavior of chrome seems to have changed so the below is no more needed in the last version*

<strike>Now if we consider the height you are facing the `stretch` effect that is also not the same in both browser. It's a bit trikcy to explain<sup>**1**</sup> but if you change the default alignment you will get the expected result within chrome:</strike>

```css
.r {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: auto; useless */
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
</div>
```

Or if you change the height using percentage value [you will make it fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/8620333) and also have what you want (this is a bit hacky because we are triggering another issue to fix the actual one)

```css
.r {
  width: 100%;
  height:658%; /*any value here with %*/
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" class="r" >
</div>
```

**Why Firefox is behaving like that?**

I don't know exactly, but the logical explanation is that Firefox is not considering the default `min-width` configuration and is giving priority to keeping ratio and not to the stretch effect.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Initially your image are defining the height of the container since they are big (around 700px in height), this height is used by the container then we apply the properties to our image so they shrink in width and since the default alignment is stretch they will stretch to the height of the container that was initially defined by their own intial height creating this rendring.

If we remove the stretch effect, the image [will try to keep their ratio](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height) since we removed the height constraint.

Same logic if we consider percentage value for height. This one will fail to `auto` and we get back to the default behavior (keeping the aspect ratio)

---

**Another alternative**

The issue arised due to the use of image that are replaced element with intrinsic dimension where the calculation of width/height is not as simple as other element.

To avoid such behavior, better wrap the image inside a `div` and avoid having them as flex items.

```css
.r {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="r"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500"></div>
  <div class="r"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500"></div>
  <div class="r"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500"></div>
  <div class="r"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TermaniAfif thanks for the explanation. so it's really firefox that implements it wrong.. who knew :/ thanks for the info!

Comment: @TheRuler I wouldn't call it *wrong* but we are having some special cases where it's not the same. Probably in the future it will get corrected so we have the same behavior

Comment: yes, wrong was the wrong word -  I meant different. thanks again!

Comment: @TheRuler I added another method explaining my previous comment of adding an extra div

Answer (score 2):

@TheRuler, The best solution is to wrap the image tag in a div or span, to render the images as per Firefox. Firefox will also work fine if you wrap the images in a div or span.

Now you can ask me why this is correct.

Basically display flex has defaults value attached to it, which are:

```
flex-grow: 0
flex-shrink: 1
flex-basis: auto
flex: 0 1 auto /* Shorthand */
```

Now, for both case Firefox and Chrome the default value is same. But still the rendering is different in the both browser specially in case of image as a flex child.

Now who is correct is debatable, and who is following the guidelines properly is also debatable.

If you look at the specification of flex, it says, flex rules should prevail over the CSS width and height properties. So in this case Firefox is shrinking the size of images to fit it properly in 600px parent.

Now if you see this example,

```
.container { display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
.container > div { flex: 1; height: 300px;}

<div class="container">
  <div>Single line in Firefox, but 300px tall in Chrome!</div>
</div>
```

So if you see this code in both browser you will see the difference. Chrome values the height property of the flex child where as Firefox doesn't value it. Same goes for image height and image width. Chrome doesn't prevail the height.

So both browser went with their own implementation, which is in this case doesn't match each other and it is debatable who is correct.

So wrap them in span or div to make it work in both the browser which should be the correct answer with no hack. Other solution will solve the problem but they are kind of hack to solve the problem.

Please let me know if you get it
Thanks

Comment: hi! thank you font the explanation, now I understand more, I've provided an answer that seems to work. could you look at it and tell me if I need to change anything. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @TemaniAfif who guided me in the right direction and I came up with this:

```css
.r {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-width: 0px;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img src="https://lundbeckconsulting.no/Temp/illu1.jpg" class="r" />
 <img src="https://lundbeckconsulting.no/Temp/illu1.jpg" class="r" />
 <img src="https://lundbeckconsulting.no/Temp/illu1.jpg" class="r" />
 <img src="https://lundbeckconsulting.no/Temp/illu1.jpg" class="r" />
</div>
```