# nested flexbox height vs max-height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

**update**: I see this strange behavior on Chrome 72. FireFox 64 is OK!

I have a problem with a nested flexbox.

In the snippet below I added a dummy XL height to `.root.container`, so that the result is exactly what I want when there are many *items* that overflow the available max-height.

Conversely, when there are few *items*, the `.root.container` should not extend to all available height.

In other terms, I want `.root.container` height to be `auto`, but I can't figure how.
Removing its dummy height, the overflow is triggered on `.root.content` instead of `.sub.content`.

Please, help me understand how flexbox works in this particular situation.

P.S. fiddle also available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3y70gum2/)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.root.container {
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 999999px; /* i want height to be 'auto' */
}

.sub.container {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
}

.root.header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sub.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.root.content {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub.content {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="root container">
  <div class="root header">header</div>
  <div class="root content">
    <div class="sub container">
      <div class="sub header">menu</div>
      <div class="sub content">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working as expected when setting the big height because `max-height:100%` [in the child element need a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1622027/8620333), if you remove the height the `max-height` will fail to auto. As a side note, Firefox will have the same output even if you remove `max-height` so the issue isn't related to `max-height`. <sup>1</sup>

Instead, you can keep the cascading flex container and rely on the default stretch alignment to obtain what you want:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.root.container {
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.sub.container {
  background-color: purple;
  width:100%; /*added this*/
}

.root.header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sub.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.root.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  display:flex; /*added this*/
}

.sub.content {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="root container">
  <div class="root header">header</div>
  <div class="root content">
    <div class="sub container">
      <div class="sub header">menu</div>
      <div class="sub content">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To better see the issue let's remove some properties and keep only the needed ones that will trigger the different behavior:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.root.container {
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.sub.container {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
}


.root.header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sub.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.root.content {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub.content {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="root container">
  <div class="root header">header</div>
  <div class="root content">
    <div class="sub container">
      <div class="sub header">menu</div>
      <div class="sub content">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the issue is related to the inner `height:100%` used on the `.sub.container`. Technically and considering the specification this height should fail to `auto` because the parent height isn't set BUT Firefox seems to be able to evalute this height. Probably due to the nested flex container where we can evaluate the parent height before knowing the content or simply a bug.

Chrome is not doing this and simply ignoring the height which is the logical behavior.

Comment: hmm that sounds right, but why the different behavior between Chrome and FF? Who is right?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti I vote for chrome, because there is  a violation in FF (I will edit my answer) but it's difficult to say.

Comment: Actually, it seems that Chrome is using *declared* height as a reference, while FF is using *computed*. If you remove `height:100%` from `.sub.container` FF renders the same as Chrome. So, for FF that `100%` is a valid reference, for Chrome it is not. Even if the Chrome behavior seems more accurate, the FF one seems more useful.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti exactly ;) I have also edited to show this ... FF is somehow doing a complex calculation (don't know exactly how) and this is the violation I am talking about

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `height: fit-content` is what you're looking for? I'm a little confused on what your desired result is.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.root.container {
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}

.sub.container {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
}

.root.header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sub.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.root.content {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub.content {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="root container">
  <div class="root header">header</div>
  <div class="root content">
    <div class="sub container">
      <div class="sub header">menu</div>
      <div class="sub content">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The desired result is actually the result you see while running my snippet. Try to run your snippet on chrome to see the problem. `fit-content`, just as `auto`, is not working.