# Calc() outputting unexpected value

Tags: css, css-grid, css-calc

What I would like to do is make the `#grid` `height` 160% of the `#grid` `width` via `calc(var(--grid-item-width) * 1.6)`, but it appears that `--grid-item-width` is being treated as a percentage of the viewport width instead of a pixel value.

The height of `#grid` is much larger than 160% of its width as can be seen in the screenshot below.

```
:root {
  --gap: 26px;
  --grid-item-width: calc(100% - calc(var(--gap) * 4));
}

#grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--grid-item-width); /* does not match */
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--gap);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: var(--grid-item-width); /* does not match */
}
```

[image]

When I print the value of `--grid-item-width` to console, it returns `calc(100% - calc( 26px * 4))`, which obviously does not help.

One of the notes about `calc()` on MDN states:

> Math expressions involving percentages for widths and heights on table columns, table column groups, table rows, table row groups, and table cells in both auto and fixed layout tables may be treated as if auto had been specified.

**Is this why `calc(var(--grid-item-width) * 1.6)` has an unexpected output in this situation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both expression are the same BUT they will not resolve to the same value because they are applied to different porperties.

So using `calc(100% - calc(var(--gap) * 4))` with `height` means that we take **100% of the parent height** (containing block) and we remove 4 gaps.

Using `calc(100% - calc(var(--gap) * 4))` with `grid-auto-columns` means that we take **100% of the element width** and we remove 4 gaps. If your element is the only one on your code so it will be full screen width thus you will end using the width of the screen.

The only way to have the same value is to be sure the height of the parent is the same as the width of the element OR avoid using percentage value and rely on different unit that will resolve the same way in both cases (`px`,`vw`,`vh`,`em`,etc)

---

Note that the value used with height may fail to `auto` in case there is [no height set on the parent element.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/8620333)

Comment: ohhhhhh right. its been a long day. i can easily do what i want to do with javascript, but id prefer to use a pure CSS method if there is one. do u know of any way i can do this besides setting the `width` and `height` to the same pixel (or otherwise) value?

Comment: share your full code, I can probably find a way depending on your situation

Comment: oh you know what. i just thought of a solution. if what ur saying is correct, instead of using `100%` i can simply use `100vw`!!!

Comment: @Anthony yes for example ;)