# percentage value in css calc

Tags: css, css-calc

While specifying a percentage value in css `calc`, how does `calc` know whether I am referring to `width` or `height`?

```
.container {
    width: calc(100% - 2vw); // 100% here is width or height ?
}
```

One may assume that it is either width or height depending on the property you are accessing, (width in this case). If that were the case,  what happens if you would like to do some calculation based on a different property? For instance, set the width based on some calculation of height? Say, set the container width to be 1.5 times height?

Comment: If you set an elements width using percent, it is its parents width the percent is based on.

Answer (score 6):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-computed-value)

> The computed value of a calc() expression is the expression with all components computed.
>
> Where percentages are **not resolved at computed-value time**, they are **not resolved in calc() expressions**, e.g. calc(100% - 100% + 1em) resolves to calc(1em + 0%), not to 1em. If there **are special rules for computing percentages** in a value (e.g. the height property), they apply whenever a calc() expression **contains percentages**.

There is no magic when using percentage inside `calc()` they will simply behave as if you aren't using `calc()`.

So using `width:100%` is exactly the same as `width:calc(100%)` which is also the same as `calc(50% + 50%)`. when you add another unit like `width:calc(100% - 2em)` it's like calculating `width:100%` then you remove `2em` from it.

Basically, `calc()` is useful when combining percentage and non-percentage value in order to have accurate and precise result like *removing `10px` from `50%` of the total width* by using `width:calc(50% - 10px)`.

---

> what happens if you would like to do some calculation based on a different property? For instance, set the width based on some calculation of height?

You cannot do such thing with `calc()`. CSS in general doesn't allow such thing. You can either consider JS, some *hacks* to preserve [ratio between width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1495407/8620333) or use CSS variable and assign the same value for different properties.

---

Related question where the use of `calc()` combined with CSS variable is missused: [Calc() outputting unexpected value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55213272/8620333)

Comment: @LGSon but it's valid to use one value (https://jsfiddle.net/os7952rx/) as one value is also an expression that is syntaxically valid inside calc() (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-syntax)

Comment: @LGSon there is the use of `*` in the expression which means `An asterisk (*) indicates that the preceding type, word, or group occurs zero or more times.` https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#mult-zero-plus

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second part of the question:

> For instance, set the width based on some calculation of height? Say, set the container width to be 1.5 times height?

You can do this with the `aspect-ratio` property:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  /* width / height ratio */
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1.5;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  some content
</div>
```

Comment: but the aspect-ratio property is not supported in some of the old browsers and even newer versions of Safari.

Comment: `aspect-ratio` has [almost 90% support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio), the old safari browsers have ~0.7% global usage (while newer versions have ~2.5%). If that’s not enough for you then don’t use it.