# Why is <p> still visible when its height is 0%

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have the following code. I don't understand why the p element is still visible when the height is 0%. Please explain, thanks!

```css
p {
  height: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>I am Ozi</p>
```

Comment: Possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/2635367) "To set a percentage height, its parent element(*) must have an explicit height." The parent of p need a specific height. Also needs overflow hiidden.

Comment: yes try line-height 0. its working..@Vikas Jadhav

Comment: Use just `0` instead of `0%`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want you to know, as you've closed this question, I searched thoroughly and couldn't find the said duplicate question. The title is not self explanatory. That's why i asked this new one.

Comment: and that's why we are here to close question as duplicate, no one is blaming you for asking the question.

Comment: @Serafin Your solution works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dont include percentage in `height`. Just specify `0` and it works.

```css
p {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>I am Ozi</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

```css
p {
 display: block;
 line-height:0;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p> hi </p>
<div>
Hi is not displayed
</div>
```