# How to make an inline-block element have 100% of parent element height

Tags: html, css

I want the green box to be 5px wide and the same height as the total height of the + and - buttons. I tried using `height: 100%` and it doesn't seem to work... what am I missing to do this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 div.canvas_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 } 
 .canvas_annotate {
     z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
 }
 div.canvas_title {
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
 }
 .canvas-zoom {
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 9px;
 }
 .canvas-zoom input {
  display: block;
  font-size: 140%;
 }
 div.zoom-button-container {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 div.zoomscale {
     width: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
 }
 .zoom-control {
     position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px dashed red;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="200" width="200" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title canvas_annotate"> canvas1 </div>

  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas2" height="200" width="200" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title canvas_annotate"> canvas2 </div>
  <div class="canvas-zoom canvas_annotate">
    <div class="zoom-control">
       <div class="zoom-button-container">
      <input type="button" class="zoom" id="zoom-in" value="+"></input>
      <input type="button" class="zoom" id="zoom-out" value="&#8722;"></input>
       </div>
    <div class="zoomscale" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add `display:flex;` to your `.zoom-control` class.

Comment: NOT duplicate -- that question wants to have height 100% of the **entire page**. Please don't rush to find duplicates.

Comment: it's not the question, it's about height:100% and more generally percentage height. Also note I didn't close as duplicate but it can be a duplicate since your issue is to understand why percentage height isn't working.

Comment: also you said : *I tried using height: 100% and it doesn't seem to work... what am I missing to do this?* --> the possible duplicate answer this question

Comment: Please try reading the entire question, I said "I want the green box to be 5px wide and **the same height as the total height of the + and - buttons**"

Comment: Because you have to give people the benefit of the doubt. Be **VERY** conservative when you assume something about someone's questions. It is **extremely** frustrating (and this has happened several times in the past) to have someone close my question within 5 minutes of posting, because they didn't read it properly and assumed someone else had asked the same question. I typically spend 30-60 minutes before posting a question like this to come up with a simple reproducible use case. I put the effort in as a poster. You should put the effort in as a reviewer.

Comment: " I gave you the canonical question dealing with percentage height in order to understand your issue" -- You know, you could have just asked that. Something like "Is your question how to set it to 100% of the page height, like this one?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css"

Comment: not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `display:flex`:

```
.zoom-control 
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

If you need more control over the size(s), you can also use `box-sizing` to account for margins, etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 div.canvas_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 } 
 .canvas_annotate {
     z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
 }
 div.canvas_title {
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
 }
 .canvas-zoom {
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 9px;
 }
 .canvas-zoom input {
  display: block;
  font-size: 140%;
 }
 div.zoom-button-container {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 div.zoomscale {
     width: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
 }
 .zoom-control {
     position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dashed red;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="200" width="200" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title canvas_annotate"> canvas1 </div>

  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas2" height="200" width="200" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title canvas_annotate"> canvas2 </div>
  <div class="canvas-zoom canvas_annotate">
    <div class="zoom-control">
       <div class="zoom-button-container">
      <input type="button" class="zoom" id="zoom-in" value="+"></input>
      <input type="button" class="zoom" id="zoom-out" value="&#8722;"></input>
       </div>
    <div class="zoomscale" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great -- thanks, I wish this stuff were easier to understand... CSS sizing and positioning is hard to deal with.

Comment: You are welcome.  My go to guide to flex : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

In order for `height: 100%;` to work properly, the parent needs to have a defined height in order for it to know how tall it should be. Without a defined height, `height: 100%;` won't work.

Try giving your `.zoom-control` class a height of `42px`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 div.canvas_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 } 
 .canvas_annotate {
     z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
 }
 div.canvas_title {
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
 }
 .canvas-zoom {
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 9px;
 }
 .canvas-zoom input {
  display: block;
  font-size: 140%;
 }
 div.zoom-button-container {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 div.zoomscale {
     width: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
 }
 .zoom-control {
     position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px dashed red;
                height: 42px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="200" width="200" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title canvas_annotate"> canvas1 </div>

  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas2" height="200" width="200" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title canvas_annotate"> canvas2 </div>
  <div class="canvas-zoom canvas_annotate">
    <div class="zoom-control">
       <div class="zoom-button-container">
      <input type="button" class="zoom" id="zoom-in" value="+"></input>
      <input type="button" class="zoom" id="zoom-out" value="&#8722;"></input>
       </div>
    <div class="zoomscale" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need the heigh to be dynamic, then you can use flexbox to achieve this.

Comment: that works but then the + and - button sizes look wrong. Is there any other way to do this without `display: flex`?

Comment: Is the height of `.zoom-control` supposed to be dynamic? Or will it be the same height?