# Launch Google Maps On Blazor

Tags: google-maps-api-3, blazor-server-side

I am trying to launch Google maps on my Server side Blazor app using JSInterop. I seem to have tried just about everything but can't get the map to show. Unfortunately there is very little samples if any about it on the internet since it's a fairly new framework and I am equally just getting my feet wet on Blazor myself, so I am probably doing a whole lot of things wrong. Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

In my component file, I have:

```
@page "/MapTest"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<style>
    #map {
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
    }
</style>

<h1>Display Google Map</h1>


<div @ref="map" id="map"></div>

@code {

    ElementReference map; // reference to the DIV

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Showgooglemap", null);
        //StateHasChanged();

    }
}
```

On my _Host.cshtml file, I have:

```
   <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxmykeyxxx&v=3"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
                var options = {
                    zoom: 14, center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById
                    ("map"), options);
        }
            //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//i tried wrapping the call in a function to see if it helps
        function Showgooglemap() {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Welcome **@flylily**, you are almost there. I run your code in my sample `Blazor-server-side` project. I only changed two things. **One** is change the height from percentage to pixel ([for percentage height HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)) and **another** is to invoke `initialize` function instead of `Showgooglemap` because `initialize` function already initialize your map on `page load` or `first render`. The complete codes are in following, try with these...

> _Host.cshtml file,

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{put-your-api-key}}&v=3"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
        var options = {
            zoom: 14, center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById
            ("map"), options);
    }   
</script>
```

> MapTest.razor component,

```
@page "/MapTest"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1>Display Google Map</h1>
<div id="map" style="height:500px;width:100%;">
</div>

@code{
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initialize", null);
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Finally, run your application & enjoy.

Comment: I thank you so much. I pulled half of my hair out  and chewed out all my nails trying to figure out why this wasn't working. You just saved me weeks of frustration.

Comment: @flylily  glad to help

Comment: It says unexpected error has occurred in my case :(

Comment: Is possible add multiple markers in MapTest.razor.component ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Maps/). It will give your **Blazor app full control over Google Static and JavaScript Maps API** as well.
Usage can be complicated so recommend to read the [documentation](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/Maps.md) for more details and check the [demo app](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/maps#google-maps).

[image]

Other [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Common.JsInterop/)  can help you **access Browsers Geolocation services** as well. See [Geo JS docs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/JsInterop.md#geolocation-js-see-demo-app) as well as [demo app](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/jsinterop#geo-js).

Comment: I stumbled across this thread randomly, but that got my attention.  (⊙⊙)

Comment: To say that usage can be complicated is an understatement and to suggest reading the documentation to be helpful is a dramatic overstatement.  This library may claim to be a good wrapper, and it might be... but I could not get it to work at all.

Comment: Google maps has tons of features. So library also bit complicated with addition of Js callbacks, etc. Demo app made it work perfectly you should check the code. If you still have issues submit it on GitHub...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `BlazorGoogleMaps` from `rungwiroon` as well. It supports

- Map
- Marker
- Symbols
- InfoWindow
- Polygon, LineString, Rectangle, Circle
- Routes
- Coordinates
- Bounds
- Styles

and is available on [Github](https://github.com/rungwiroon/BlazorGoogleMaps) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorGoogleMaps).

I'm using it and it works really well.

Comment: I looked at this, but cannot find any good documentation. Even the simple bit of code on the home page does not match the code in the samples.  Have you found any good documentation or sample usage?  I'm just trying to do something simple like setting the height on the GoogleMap component.

Comment: I am supporter and i am lazy to fill all documentation nicely :). I could assure that server side sample have allmost all possible variations with map

Comment: @Kevon I just downloaded the zip file and opened it in Visual Studio, all ran fine. The code samples are the best documentation 