# Blazor: Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, blazor

Morning,

So currently in my project i am using an embeded google maps API with JS in my blazor project. The map is on the page and fucntional. I used tips from this following article on stack overflow ([Launch Google Maps On Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524910/launch-google-maps-on-blazor))

Using the following JS in my _Hosts file
I need to remove certain features of the map in JS

```
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
            var options = {
                zoom: 14, center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById
                ("map"), options);
        }
    </script>
```

Any pointers on where i can find the code to turn features off?

I need to remove these features that open full screen or a new tab

[image: I need to remove these features that open full screen or a new tab **image**]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried disabling 'disableDefaultUI: true'

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
}
```

Check documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Comment: Thank you! Yes that worked for the full screen however its not removing the small buttons at the bottom. I will have a look into it with the link you provided thank you. Couldn't find anything online

Comment: try `
  scaleControl: true,
  overviewMapControl: true,`