# Implementing js-script into component in Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

Can you please explain how to integrate the script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A1d532a41650954ba7f9ebe8975d9ebff1be172d29fb570d1b8c94fb9bfb45c66&amp;width=500&amp;height=720&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
```

I want to have this script in the Blazor's component because I need to show the map on one page

Comment: api-maps.yandex.ru hrmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this script tag in Page/_Layout.cshtml file in-order to use this script.

Comment: Thanks. And how can I call this script in the component?

Comment: You dont have to call this script it will be injected into blazor application once your app startsup, if by calling you mean call some function from within this script?

Comment: I put this script in index.html (cause I have Blazor Webassembly). This script should display the map but there is nothing when I'm starting project.

Comment: [similar question for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524910/launch-google-maps-on-blazor) this one might help you have a look at this