# Migrate xamarin xaml page with map to MAUI razor page

Tags: dictionary, xamarin, blazor, maui

I want to migrate my xamarin application to the new MAUI project template.
In Xamarin, I have a page view (xaml) with a map control bound to the viewmodel Map property

```
<ContentView HeightRequest="650" Content="{Binding Map}"/>
```

Now in MAUI, using BlazorWebView, I am trying to create a new razor page but I do not know how to bind the MAUI Map control to the razor page.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance.

I want to bind the Map property of type Microsoft.Maui.Maps.Map to the Map.razor page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to bind the Map property of type Microsoft.Maui.Maps.Map to the Map.razor page.

In other words, what you mean is to use native MAUI control in Blazor. You can refer to this: [How to use Native MAUI Control in .razor pages](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/315), [Allow Native MAUI Controls to be placed and used from .razor pages in Blazor Hybrid App](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9378). It is controversial. The direction provided by one of them is an [experimental release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/advanced/access-native-controls).

You can try to [use Map directly in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524910/launch-google-maps-on-blazor), or use [Map in MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0).