# Background image not showing up in div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div class="soundscapeImgDiv"> </div>
```

In the CSS I try and set its background like so:

```
.soundscapeImgDiv {
  /* background-color: white; */
  background-image:url('images/testImg.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;

  width: 280px;
  height: 85%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

but when I do no image shows up. If I just leave the color then the box shows up.

**How can I fix this and make the image show up as the background?**

**Update:**

I am currently getting

> GET file:///images/testImg.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

In the terminal. For `background-image:url('/images/testImg.png');`

[image]

Comment: Please hit `F12` and see if there are any console errors. The most common cause of this is that the image is not loading & the page is throwing a `404 error`. If there is a `404 error`, please read more on [Relative Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) and ensure yours is correct.

Comment: Could you check the relative paths first?

Comment: Where's your image located?

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl the CSS file is inside a folder called CSS while the images folder is found at the same level as the CSS folder.

Comment: Add a picture of your folder structure so we can help further

Comment: try this ```../images/testImg.png```

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl it worked!? I did that before and it did not work...

Comment: I've updated my answer. Make sure to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `background-repeat` property

explore.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/explore.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="soundscapeImgDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

explore.css:

```
div.soundscapeImgDiv {
  /* background-color: white; */
  background-image: url("../images/testImg.png");

  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 280px;
  height: 85%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Triple check your folder structure:

> file:///Users/username/Desktop/Portals.com/**css**/**images**/testImg.png

I believe you are aiming to have something like this:
`file:///Users/username/Desktop/Portals.com/images/testImg.png`

See this [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/dnlbnrstr/eLqgr063/6/)

Comment: I already do:   background-image:url('images/testImg.png') no-repeat;

Comment: Try: `background-image: url("./images/testImg.png");`

Comment: Remove the ```no-repeat``` part. Use the the ```background-repeat``` property instead or use ```background: url("images/testImg.png") no-repeat;```

Comment: @EGC GET file:///Users/username/Desktop/Portals.com/css/images/testImg.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: you're missing a slash ```/``` ... try this ```background-image:url('/images/testImg.png');```

Comment: Okay.. well try this one: `background-image: url("../images/testImg.png");`

Comment: Or supply an image of your folder structure (where your image is & the HTML you're trying to reference it from)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are mixing the `background-image` property and the `background repeat` property.

If you want to declare both in one line use `background` property:

```css
.soundscapeImgDiv {
  /* background-color: white; */
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/150/450') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;

  width: 280px;
  height: 85%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="soundscapeImgDiv"> </div>
```

Make sure that there is an actual image on the path you provide:
**`url('images/testImg.png')` this line means that you truly got a file name testImg.png inside `image` folder on the same place where you excecute your html file.**

Answer (score 1):

I think the no-repeat statement is messing with the code, try removing no-repeat or using:-

```
.soundscapeImgDiv {
/* background-color: white; */
background-image:url('images/testImg.png');
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width: 280px;
height: 85%;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The are **two factors** makes your image not working:

- the property `background-image` doesn't accept `no-repeat` as a second parameter, you may use `background` shorthand property to pass `url() no-repeat`
- the Percentage value of the height dosent work without explicitly declaring the height of `body` or `html` you may need to see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)  or replace it by `vh,px` it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML, CSS and Image files are all located in different locations.  Since your CSS file is located in a folder called CSS. When you use the path images/testImg.png, the css file is looking for a folder called images inside of the CSS folder.  In Order to get onto the correct path you need to use .. to move up one folder. So when the CSS file runs and looks for the image, ../images/testImg.png, will move up and out of the CSS folder and then into the images folder.