# What does it mean when an elements dimensions are "auto x auto"?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

In my Angular app, I am using Bootstrap, and some elements are generated by the Bootstrap framework. I notice that many of these elements have dimensions `auto x auto` and this seems to be affecting the behaviour of elements below it (for example, when I set the height to `100%` it is not filling the full height of the parent as I would expect)

So what is `auto x auto`, how does it get set and exactly what effect does it have on the rest of the page ?

[image: DevTools auto x auto]

Comment: auto means there is no explicit value and the content + the nature of the element will define the final value.

Comment: `auto x auto` just means that the size of the box is determined by content. Unless your parent element has a specific height set, a child with `100%` will not mean anything.

Comment: relate (probably a duplicate if only the height:100% is bothering you): https://stackoverflow.com/q/1622027/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the element does not have the width and height set in css.
For a block element, it means that it will have the witdh of the parent and height determined by its content, for an inline element - its dimensions will be determined by its content.

You are not able to set `height:100%` because the parent element also does not have a height set.

You will be able to set `height:100%` if the parent element has some explicit height or if its position is `absolute`.