# css blend/blur/merge backgrounds images

Tags: html, css, reactjs, blurry

I work on a website, this is just a demo here in ReactJS :  https://poc-b-i-o-meteo.netlify.com/

The probleme is with the background.

The concept is easy, the app is composed with 4 parts, the top with meteo with no background and 3 parts each on with a different background. The app must be mobile & responsive, each part have different content so different height.

[image]

Now i want to make a nice effect between each part (météo & 1 ; 1&2; 2&3) like this :

[image]

So how to make each part to be over the bottom of the previous part for some pixel and to make it blend together nicely (like we can do with 2 png in photoshop with transparence ). This effect should be done in css because it should be there from mobile to wide screen.

Previously i tried :

1. with 3 png who contained transparence, it doesn't work for two raison. PNG are SOOOOO heavy and it shown only a precise screen width.
2. by adding a relative zone to bottom/top of the component `Categorie` with `linear-gradient` but render little ugly

1)  APP.JS

```
import Meteo from "./components/Meteo";
import Categorie from "./components/Categorie";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h5 style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}>Météo</h5>
      <header className="App-header">
        <Meteo />
        <Categorie name="air" display="Air" bgpos="bottom" {/* bottomOpacity*/} />

        <Categorie name="sol" display="Sol" bgpos="center"  {/*  bottomOpacity topOpacity*/} />

        <Categorie name="eau" display="Eau" bgpos="top" {/* topOpacity */}/>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2) Categorie.js

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  leftText: {
    textAlign: "left",
    width: "auto",
    display: "inline-block"
  },
  responsive: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: "1000px",
    height: "auto"
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  overlay: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(13,53,78, 0.6)",

    color: "white",
    position: "relative"
  },

  topOpacity: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: -2,
    width: "100%",
    height: 75,
    background: "linear-gradient( to top, transparent , rgba(13,53,78,0.9 ) )",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
  },
  bottomOpacity: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: -2,
    width: "100%",
    height: 75,
    background:
      "linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent , rgba(13,53,78, 0.9 ) )",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
  },

  padding: {
    padding: "auto",
    paddingTop: 85,
    paddingBottom: 85
  }
}));

export default function Categorie(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  let ref = useRef(null);
  let size = useComponentSize(ref);
  let { width, height } = size;

  const filename = {
    air: "air.jpg",
    eau: "eau.jpg",
    sol: "sol.jpg"
  };

  let backgd = {
    backgroundImage: `url('./photos/${filename[props.name]}')  `,
    backgroundPosition: props.bgpos || "center",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: `${width}px ${height}px`,
    width: "100%"
  };

  return (
    <div style={backgd} ref={ref}>
      <div className={classes.overlay}>
        {props.topOpacity && <div className={classes.topOpacity} />}
        <div className={classes.padding}>
          ... CONTENT
        </div>
        {props.bottomOpacity && <div className={classes.bottomOpacity} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done using mask.

Here is a simplified example:

```css
.box {
  height:60vh;
  font-size:50px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:-50px;
  bottom:-50px;
  background:var(--img) center/cover;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(transparent ,#fff 50px calc(100% - 50px),transparent);
          mask:linear-gradient(transparent ,#fff 50px calc(100% - 50px),transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1002/800/800.jpg)">text 1</div>
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/id/109/800/800.jpg)">text 2</div>
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/id/107/800/800.jpg)">text 3</div>
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/id/177/800/800.jpg)">text 4</div>
```

Comment: the code do what i need. do you know how to use ::before with reactjs ? can this be done with two differente class name insted of box + before ?

Comment: @AlainIb yes, add an extra element inside your div (another div) then apply the CSS to it insitead. You can also remove the CSS variable and use the background as inline style

Comment: sorry but do you have an example ? i get blank screen because of relative position in box class

Comment: really sory to insist. 
it's still get hidden element due to absolute. can you take a look at https://poc-b-i-o-meteo.netlify.com/ ? thanks

Comment: @AlainIb your issue is the use of height:100%, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1622027/8620333

Comment: i updated the code and deployed it https://poc-b-i-o-meteo.netlify.com/

now i got an issu with the background who is displayed as it's own heigth. i need to display it at the child height? any fix please ?

Comment: i created a sandbox here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-field-mnw6g