# How to overcome the space between content and footer when the entire content is shorter than the screen size

Tags: html, css

After applying the below style, a gap between entire content and footer occurs. And then I applied **min-height** in the HTML **object** tag and parent div as mentioned by the last member in the below link, still it not reflects in the page. What I'm missing?

[Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

```
div#container{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 456px);
}

object {
    background-color: #398DCB !important;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 456px);
}
```

HTML

```
  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head> 
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">  
          <object id="obj" data="details.html"  width="100%" type="text/html"></object> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Updated:**

details.html

```
<div>
 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..! 
</div>
```

It appeared fine when we add content directly inside the **object** tag, the issue arises when we do the same by using **data** attribute to load the content.

Comment: @nthnchu Could you have a look at it?

Comment: Depends on your design but from the little you pasted you could do a easy one and have the body background-color to be blue.

Comment: @Dejan.S Agree, but some page may have different background color. And some page has only dropdown and button in the initial page load. So if I make it standard height based on (content - (header + footer) px) in min-height it will serve my purpose.

Comment: @Dejan.S Please take a look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/qhrcb7n5/

Comment: @Dejan.S It works fine with your updated example but the issue occurs when I try to load the same data from another file. I have edited the question give more clarification.

Comment: @Dejan.S   Copy & Paste the sample data multiple times in the details.html to recreate the issue. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this that you use flex on the body, or a container and use flex on that. Flex-grow on the container will always take the available space left.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: aqua;
}

object {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">header</header>
  <object id="obj" width="100%" type="text/html">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

      Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

      Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

      Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

      Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

      Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

      Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

      Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..!
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

      Ut enim ad minima veniam quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis..! abc


    </object>
  <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your example works fine for your layout but I'm facing issue with object tag here. Please take a look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/qhrcb7n5/

Comment: @Dev I updated my example with your fiddle code. You have to have that on the body.