# How to set map container height dynamically for a Mapbox GL JS map inside of a Ionic/React project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, ionic5

So the problem I am having is that whenever I switch the size of the map container in my project to something other than a hardcoded amount of pixels, the map effectively disappears. I think that it might be setting the height to 0 somehow or it is not properly getting the % to the container.

CSS:

```css
.map-container {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: cadetblue;
}
```

React Render bit that it is constructed in:

```html
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="sidebar">
              Longitude: {this.state.lng} | Latitude: {this.state.lat} | Zoom: {this.state.zoom}
        </div>
        <div ref={this.mapContainer} className="map-container" />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

What its supposed to look like (when container height is set to hardcoded 800px):

[Hardcoded container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuEeb.png)

What it looks like with height set to 100% or really any other percent:

["dynamic" container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIj0e.png)

The overall goal here is to make the entire window you can see be sized to whatever size window the user has and the map and other panes to be sized properly so they are fixed in between the header and footer. I think I recall seeing somewhere that to get the heights to go by %, you need to have all of the other pieces in its ancestry set to the right percentages, but I am not entirely clear on how to do that within my react app.

Side note: Probably needs to be a separate question, but I can't get the footer to stop hiding the bottom of my map. Think it's a problem of the IonContent not interacting with the IonFooter correctly. Any ideas would help here.

code for reference:

```html
<IonPage>
            <IonHeader>
                
                <IonToolbar color="primary">
                <IonGrid>
                    <IonRow>
                    
                    <IonCol>
                    <div className="home-title">
                        <h2 color="light" >
                        Welcome to IPSS!
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    </IonCol>
                    
                    <IonCol>
                    </IonCol>
                    
                    <IonCol >
                        <IonSearchbar>
                        </IonSearchbar>
                    </IonCol>
        
                    </IonRow>
                </IonGrid>
                </IonToolbar>
                
            </IonHeader>
            
            <IonContent className="home-content">
                <IonGrid >
                
                <IonRow> 
                    {/* To be replaced with countryInfo component src: countryInfo.tsx */}
                    <IonCol class="menu1">
                    
                        <IonRow>
                        <IonCol> <IonIcon size= "large" icon={add}></IonIcon> </IonCol>
                        
                        <IonCol>
                            <div>
                                {selectedCountry}
                            </div>
                        </IonCol>
                        
                        <IonCol>
                            <IonIcon class="ion-float-right" size= "large" icon={arrowForward}></IonIcon>
                        </IonCol>
                        
                        </IonRow>
                        <IonRow>
                        
                        <IonText>
                            <p className="para1"> 
                            Population:  1<br/>
                            Median Age: 34 <br/>
                            Pop. Growth Rate <br/>
                            Birth Rate: 18.2/ 1000 <br/>
                            Death Rate: 7.45/ 1000 <br/>
                            Infant mortality rate: 30 / 1000 <br/>
                            Life Expectancy: 72.5 
                            </p>
                        </IonText>
                        </IonRow>
                        
                        
                    
        
                    </IonCol>
                    
                    <IonCol>
                    {/* To be replaced with regionItem component src: regionItem.tsx  use flyto from mapbox */}
                    <IonContent scrollEvents={true} scrollY={true} className="regionSelect">
                        <IonItem detail={true}>
                        
                        </IonItem>
                        <IonItem>
        
                        </IonItem>
                        <IonItem>
        
                        </IonItem>
                    </IonContent>
                    </IonCol>
                
                    <IonCol>
                        {/* Home page chart*/}
                        <HomeChart selectedCountry={this.state.selectedCountry}></HomeChart>
                    </IonCol>
                </IonRow>
               
                <IonRow>
                    
                    <IonCol>
                    {/* Map component src: Map.js */}
                    <WorldMap selectedCountry={selectedCountry} onCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange}></WorldMap>
                    </IonCol>
                </IonRow>
                
                </IonGrid>
            </IonContent>
            
            <IonFooter>
                <IonToolbar color="primary">
                
                <IonButtons slot="start">
                
                    <Link to="/HomePage" className="footer-icons">
                        <IonButton>
                            <IonIcon  size= "large" slot="start" icon={homeOutline} ></IonIcon>    
                                Home 
                        </IonButton>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/Page2" className="footer-icons">
                        <IonButton >
                            <IonIcon  size= "large" slot="start" icon={locationOutline}  ></IonIcon>
                            Page 2
                        </IonButton>
                    </Link>

                </IonButtons>
                
                <IonButtons slot="end">
                    <IonButton>
                    <IonIcon  size= "large"  icon={globeOutline} ></IonIcon>
                        
                    </IonButton>
                    <IonButton>
                    <IonIcon  size= "large"  icon={statsChartOutline} ></IonIcon>
        
                    </IonButton>
                    <IonButton>
                    <IonIcon  size= "large"  icon={saveOutline} ></IonIcon>
                        
                    </IonButton>
                    <IonButton>
                    <IonIcon  size= "large" icon={shareOutline} ></IonIcon>
                    </IonButton>
                    
                    
        
                    <IonButton>
                    <IonIcon  size= "large" icon={listOutline} ></IonIcon>
                    </IonButton>
                    
                </IonButtons>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonFooter>
                
            
            </IonPage>
```

A little additional info:
Project is made with React 17.0.2, Ionic/React 5.6.6, and map box gl 2.2.0
The map is a custom react component generally set up like this example from the map box docs: [Link](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/#final-product)

Answer (score 1):

Kind of figured it out, mostly a css problem. The default height for a div is height: auto, so since I did not have a height set for the parent component, it was trying to make the height of the map container 100% of auto, which turns out to be 0. I actually changed directions and started using vh, which is a css thing that is a % relation to the viewport and it seems to be working better. Good explanation here: [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Comment: When I changed the height of the container to 100% vh, a scrollbar appears and the map extends beyond the viewport, did you have this issue?

Comment: Check the inspector and for each DIV that has a height of 0 add these two CSS declarations: `height: 100%; max-height: 500px;`. Change 500 to whatever you like.