# How does setting a parent div to min-h-screen affect its children?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm having trouble making my react app fill the whole screen while being able to size its children properly. Why is it that this works:

```
<div className="h-screen bg-blue-500">
    <div className="h-1/2 bg-red-500"></div>
</div>
```

and this doesnt:

```
<div className="min-h-screen bg-blue-500">
    <div className="h-1/2 bg-red-500"></div>
</div>
```

I've looked through the docs and other posts but nothing really touches on this specific problem. Also although h-screen makes it so that the children behave as expected, it doesn't fill the whole screen when there's a need to scroll. I'd appreciate any input, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply how CSS works.  The Tailwind class `min-h-screen` equates to `min-height: 100vh;` and the class `h-1/2` equates to `height: 50%`.  You cannot use a percentage as a height inside a container that doesn't have an explicit height (i.e., if its height is auto such that it is dependent upon the content inside of it).

The [formal definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#formal_definition) in the CSS specification says

> [t]he percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

---

One way to work around this is to add the `grid` class to the parent element.  CSS grid containers have intrinsic height and width, so it is possible for your `height: 50%` child to use the intrinsic height of the grid to calculate its relative height.

This is fine if your container only has a single div such as in your example.  However, the empty div will collapse as you add more content in one or more additional children containers.

If that's not the behavior you want, and you always want the one container to be 50% of the parent even if it overflows the min-height, then you can use `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr` (or in the case of Tailwind `grid-rows-2` which translates to `repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))`) instead of height on the child:

```css
<div className="min-h-screen bg-blue-500 grid grid-rows-2">
  <div className="bg-red-500"></div>
  <div>
    <p>Add as much or as little content here as you like.</p>
    <p>Both child divs will always have the same height of 50% relative to the parent</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, so what would you say would be the best/most typical solution to the problem?

Comment: Added some suggestions above